# How do I Sort a Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have CSV data loaded into a multidimensional array. In this way each "row" is a record and each "column" contains the same type of data.  I am using the function below to load my CSV file.

```
function f_parse_csv($file, $longest, $delimiter)
{
  $mdarray = array();
  $file    = fopen($file, "r");
  while ($line = fgetcsv($file, $longest, $delimiter))
  {
    array_push($mdarray, $line);
  }
  fclose($file);
  return $mdarray;
}
```

I need to be able to specify a column to sort so that it rearranges the rows.  One of the columns contains date information in the format of `Y-m-d H:i:s` and I would like to be able to sort with the most recent date being the first row.

Comment: (2 yrs later...) If you're sorting dates stored as strings, you may first need to use strtotime

[1] http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @deceze, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1597736/1709587 seems like a better dupe target to me. It's a more exact duplicate and the answers there consequently get to the point faster than yours at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/1709587 while collectively having the same level of detail. What say you to switching the target? (Disclosure: am possibly biased as the author of one of the answers at the dupe target I'm proposing.)

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can use [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($mdarray as $key => $row) {
    // replace 0 with the field's index/key
    $dates[$key]  = $row[0];
}

array_multisort($dates, SORT_DESC, $mdarray);
```

For PHP >= 5.5.0 just extract the column to sort by.  No need for the loop:

```
array_multisort(array_column($mdarray, 0), SORT_DESC, $mdarray);
```

Comment: So in this example, $mdarray might be a two-dimensional array, like an array of database records. In this example, 0 is the index of the 'date' column in each record (or row). So you construct the $dates array (basically the same array, but with only that column), and tell the array_multisort function to sort $mdarray based on that particular column's values.

Comment: For clarity, you might add to the beginning of this example `$dates = array();`

Comment: Should array_multisort work with associative arrays (changing `$row[0]` to `$row['whatever']`?   No go here.   After I changed my array to numeric the function worked as expected.

Comment: Isn't the inclusion of the `$key` unnecessary when using *array_multisort()*? It seems simpler and more intentional to write `foreach ($mdarray as $row) { $sortByDate[]  = $row['date']; }` then `array_multisort( $sortByDate, SORT_DESC, $mdarray );` (your semantic mileage my vary).

Comment: If `array_multi_sort()` is the answer, the question was not understood. While technically it will work, there usually is a better solution with a user generated compare function and the usage of a `usort()` function. It's easier to maintain. With multisort, you usually create code that prepares the data for sorting. If the data structure changes, that code might be thrown away. With usort(), you change the compare function - in the same way you changed the data structure.

Comment: There's a more extensive example of this answer now on the PHP array_multisort page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#example-4928.

Comment: Warning: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent

Answer (score 349):

### Introducing: a very generalized solution for PHP 5.3+

I 'd like to add my own solution here, since it offers features that other answers do not.

Specifically, advantages of this solution include:

1. It's **reusable**: you specify the sort column as a variable instead of hardcoding it.
2. It's **flexible**: you can specify multiple sort columns (as many as you want) -- additional columns are used as tiebreakers between items that initially compare equal.
3. It's **reversible**: you can specify that the sort should be reversed -- individually for each column.
4. It's **extensible**: if the data set contains columns that cannot be compared in a "dumb" manner (e.g. date strings) you can also specify how to convert these items to a value that can be directly compared (e.g. a `DateTime` instance).
5. It's **associative if you want**: this code takes care of sorting items, but *you* select the actual sort function (`usort` or `uasort`).
6. Finally, it does not use `array_multisort`: while `array_multisort` is convenient, it depends on creating a projection of all your input data before sorting. This consumes time and memory and may be simply prohibitive if your data set is large.

#### The code

```
function make_comparer() {
    // Normalize criteria up front so that the comparer finds everything tidy
    $criteria = func_get_args();
    foreach ($criteria as $index => $criterion) {
        $criteria[$index] = is_array($criterion)
            ? array_pad($criterion, 3, null)
            : array($criterion, SORT_ASC, null);
    }

    return function($first, $second) use (&$criteria) {
        foreach ($criteria as $criterion) {
            // How will we compare this round?
            list($column, $sortOrder, $projection) = $criterion;
            $sortOrder = $sortOrder === SORT_DESC ? -1 : 1;

            // If a projection was defined project the values now
            if ($projection) {
                $lhs = call_user_func($projection, $first[$column]);
                $rhs = call_user_func($projection, $second[$column]);
            }
            else {
                $lhs = $first[$column];
                $rhs = $second[$column];
            }

            // Do the actual comparison; do not return if equal
            if ($lhs < $rhs) {
                return -1 * $sortOrder;
            }
            else if ($lhs > $rhs) {
                return 1 * $sortOrder;
            }
        }

        return 0; // tiebreakers exhausted, so $first == $second
    };
}
```

### How to use

Throughout this section I will provide links that sort this sample data set:

```
$data = array(
    array('zz', 'name' => 'Jack', 'number' => 22, 'birthday' => '12/03/1980'),
    array('xx', 'name' => 'Adam', 'number' => 16, 'birthday' => '01/12/1979'),
    array('aa', 'name' => 'Paul', 'number' => 16, 'birthday' => '03/11/1987'),
    array('cc', 'name' => 'Helen', 'number' => 44, 'birthday' => '24/06/1967'),
);
```

#### The basics

The function `make_comparer` accepts a variable number of arguments that define the desired sort and returns a function that you are supposed to use as the argument to `usort` or `uasort`.

The simplest use case is to pass in the key that you 'd like to use to compare data items. For example, to sort `$data` by the `name` item you would do

```
usort($data, make_comparer('name'));
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/g5jNqs)**.

The key can also be a number if the items are numerically indexed arrays. For the example in the question, this would be

```
usort($data, make_comparer(0)); // 0 = first numerically indexed column
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/upHxqf)**.

#### Multiple sort columns

You can specify multiple sort columns by passing additional parameters to `make_comparer`. For example, to sort by "number" and then by the zero-indexed column:

```
usort($data, make_comparer('number', 0));
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/C5OqJT)**.

### Advanced features

More advanced features are available if you specify a sort column as an array instead of a simple string. This array should be numerically indexed, and must contain these items:

```
0 => the column name to sort on (mandatory)
1 => either SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC (optional)
2 => a projection function (optional)
```

Let's see how we can use these features.

#### Reverse sort

To sort by name descending:

```
usort($data, make_comparer(['name', SORT_DESC]));
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/eLUqjb)**.

To sort by number descending and then by name descending:

```
usort($data, make_comparer(['number', SORT_DESC], ['name', SORT_DESC]));
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/RpyQZ3)**.

#### Custom projections

In some scenarios you may need to sort by a column whose values do not lend well to sorting. The "birthday" column in the sample data set fits this description: it does not make sense to compare birthdays as strings (because e.g. "01/01/1980" comes before "10/10/1970"). In this case we want to specify how to *project* the actual data to a form that *can* be compared directly with the desired semantics.

Projections can be specified as any type of [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php): as strings, arrays, or anonymous functions. A projection is assumed to accept one argument and return its projected form.

It should be noted that while projections are similar to the custom comparison functions used with `usort` and family, they are simpler (you only need to convert one value to another) and take advantage of all the functionality already baked into `make_comparer`.

Let's sort the example data set without a projection and see what happens:

```
usort($data, make_comparer('birthday'));
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/GvXmoM)**.

That was not the desired outcome. But we can use [`date_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) as a projection:

```
usort($data, make_comparer(['birthday', SORT_ASC, 'date_create']));
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/sZE4hO)**.

This is the correct order that we wanted.

There are many more things that projections can achieve. For example, a quick way to get a case-insensitive sort is to use `strtolower` as a projection.

That said, I should also mention that it's better to not use projections if your data set is large: in that case it would be much faster to project all your data manually up front and then sort without using a projection, although doing so will trade increased memory usage for faster sort speed.

Finally, here is an example that uses all the features: it first sorts by number descending, then by birthday ascending:

```
usort($data, make_comparer(
    ['number', SORT_DESC],
    ['birthday', SORT_ASC, 'date_create']
));
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/RLmvsm)**.

Comment: @Jon When I check your last action (with the callback `date_create`), the birthday are in the wrong order. Could you confirm ? I get `01/12/1979`, `03/11/1987`, `12/03/1980` and `24/06/1967`. If I use `strtotime` instead, I get a good result. I assume it's DateTime that's broken.

Comment: @DavidBélanger: Which URL exactly? All examples work correctly both on ideone.com and on my local machine.

Comment: Hey, @Jon, I dont know how I can contact you but through comment. I see you created tag "multidimensional array", but we need also "multidimensional data" for similar term in data visualization and related disciplines. I can't create tags, may I ask you to create one, if you find it makes sense?

Comment: @VividD: I didn't create the tag myself, and tag creation cannot happen by itself. New tags are implicitly created when someone with the required privileges uses them to tag a question; given that I have never seen and probably will never see a question that I feel should be tagged like that, I can't really help.

Comment: Could you give an example how to implement case-insensitive sort? I tried converting projection to lowercase but it won't work...

Comment: @Andrew: [Example](http://ideone.com/5IH1zt). But remember that this is inefficient so don't do it if your data set is not small.

Comment: @Jon thanks, i just tried it and it's 0.006 sec slower than without it, sorting 200 rows. I think i'll accept this kind of inefficiency :)

Comment: I have another array of values that I would like to sort a column against and the value in the column can have multiple matches. The sort array is of file types so I always want file types of a list of files to show in a specific order. Is it possible in this construct?

Comment: @Ecropolis: Please post a good example of your input(s) and desired output somewhere (e.g. ideone.com or pastebin.com) so that we can eliminate misunderstandings.

Comment: @Jon - Thank you here are example arrays with comments. http://ideone.com/utbrNt

Comment: @Ecropolis: OK, so you can make an array where keys are filetypes and values are "weights" (smaller weight = item goes on top) with `$weights = array_flip($sort_array)`. `$weights` is now `['mp4' => 0, 'mpeg' => 1, ...]`. You can then utilize this in the comparer by sorting on filetype and using this as a projection: `function($t) use ($weights) { return $weights[$t]; })`.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you @Jon. I updated  http://ideone.com/utbrNt for the complete example of how to use this function to sort an array using another for reference sort values.

Comment: @Ecropolis: You have extra quotes around `function($t) ...` that need to be removed. Cheers!

Comment: @Jon - Thanks for all of your help. I tried to implement this on my server and I get this:PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' -- I tried different variation, I'm just a bit lost on how this really works. I'm on v5.3.28 - ideone.com runs php 5.4 - is that the issue?

Comment: @Ecropolis: PHP 5.3 does not support the short `[...]` array syntax, you will have to use `array(...)` instead. I didn't do that in the examples for extra brevity, but `make_comparer` itself is compatible with 5.3.

Comment: @Jon Great answer and I agree that this is like a web site rather than answer. Thanks. Only have one question. How can I make it work to run for objects?

Comment: @YahyaE: Sorting arrays of objects? Replace `$first[$column]` with `$first->$column`, and same for `$second`. Four replacements in total.

Comment: mine is a 4D array ? how can i pass the index if that possible ?

Comment: @Dashrath: I'm not sure what you structure is. Either pass in `$array['index']` if you want to get rid of the top level, or else use a projection `function($sub) { return $sub['index']; }` if you want to get rid of a mid-level dimension named `index`.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine I read the question, but you don't show what you tried to do. It seems just `usort($data['content'], get_comparer('price'))` would be enough, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @Jon thanks for your comment. However, I am still reading your answer and trying to understand it. If needed i will use the same in my project. Just had one doubt. I am not sure it will work with my data/array or not. In your example data is in different format.

Answer (score 34):

With [usort](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). Here's a generic solution, that you can use for different columns:

```
class TableSorter {
  protected $column;
  function __construct($column) {
    $this->column = $column;
  }
  function sort($table) {
    usort($table, array($this, 'compare'));
    return $table;
  }
  function compare($a, $b) {
    if ($a[$this->column] == $b[$this->column]) {
      return 0;
    }
    return ($a[$this->column] < $b[$this->column]) ? -1 : 1;
  }
}
```

To sort by first column:

```
$sorter = new TableSorter(0); // sort by first column
$mdarray = $sorter->sort($mdarray);
```

Comment: I get Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' on the second line of that class.

Comment: Replace "protrected" with "var" and "__construct" with "TableSorter", and it will work in PHP4. Notice however, that PHP4 is discontinued.

Comment: I set PHP to v5, didn't know it was running v4 by default. Having looked at it for a while I think I understand how to modify it for different types of sorts as well

Answer (score 11):

### Multiple row sorting using a closure

Here's another approach using uasort() and an anonymous callback function (closure). I've used that function regularly. **PHP 5.3 required** – no more dependencies!

```
/**
 * Sorting array of associative arrays - multiple row sorting using a closure.
 * See also: http://the-art-of-web.com/php/sortarray/
 *
 * @param array $data input-array
 * @param string|array $fields array-keys
 * @license Public Domain
 * @return array
 */
function sortArray( $data, $field ) {
    $field = (array) $field;
    uasort( $data, function($a, $b) use($field) {
        $retval = 0;
        foreach( $field as $fieldname ) {
            if( $retval == 0 ) $retval = strnatcmp( $a[$fieldname], $b[$fieldname] );
        }
        return $retval;
    } );
    return $data;
}

/* example */
$data = array(
    array( "firstname" => "Mary", "lastname" => "Johnson", "age" => 25 ),
    array( "firstname" => "Amanda", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 18 ),
    array( "firstname" => "James", "lastname" => "Brown", "age" => 31 ),
    array( "firstname" => "Patricia", "lastname" => "Williams", "age" => 7 ),
    array( "firstname" => "Michael", "lastname" => "Davis", "age" => 43 ),
    array( "firstname" => "Sarah", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 24 ),
    array( "firstname" => "Patrick", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 27 )
);

$data = sortArray( $data, 'age' );
$data = sortArray( $data, array( 'lastname', 'firstname' ) );
```

Answer (score 8):

I know it's 2 years since this question was asked and answered, but here's another function that sorts a two-dimensional array. It accepts a variable number of arguments, allowing you to pass in more than one key (ie column name) to sort by. PHP 5.3 required.

```
function sort_multi_array ($array, $key)
{
  $keys = array();
  for ($i=1;$i<func_num_args();$i++) {
    $keys[$i-1] = func_get_arg($i);
  }

  // create a custom search function to pass to usort
  $func = function ($a, $b) use ($keys) {
    for ($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++) {
      if ($a[$keys[$i]] != $b[$keys[$i]]) {
        return ($a[$keys[$i]] < $b[$keys[$i]]) ? -1 : 1;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  };

  usort($array, $func);

  return $array;
}
```

Try it here: http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/sort_multi_array

Comment: Could the first 3 lines of the function be replaced with `$keys = func_get_args(); array_unshift($keys);`?

Answer (score 7):

You can sort an array using [usort](https://www.php.net/usort) function.

```
 $array = array(
  array('price'=>'1000.50','product'=>'product 1'),
  array('price'=>'8800.50','product'=>'product 2'),
  array('price'=>'200.0','product'=>'product 3')
);

function cmp($a, $b) {
  return $a['price'] > $b['price'];
}
usort($array, "cmp");
print_r($array);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 134.50
            [product] => product 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 2033.0
            [product] => product 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 8340.50
            [product] => product 2
        )

)
```

[Example](https://qoify.com/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-given-key-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a php4/php5 class that will sort one or more fields:

```
// a sorter class
//  php4 and php5 compatible
class Sorter {

  var $sort_fields;
  var $backwards = false;
  var $numeric = false;

  function sort() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $array = $args[0];
    if (!$array) return array();
    $this->sort_fields = array_slice($args, 1);
    if (!$this->sort_fields) return $array();

    if ($this->numeric) {
      usort($array, array($this, 'numericCompare'));
    } else {
      usort($array, array($this, 'stringCompare'));
    }
    return $array;
  }

  function numericCompare($a, $b) {
    foreach($this->sort_fields as $sort_field) {
      if ($a[$sort_field] == $b[$sort_field]) {
        continue;
      }
      return ($a[$sort_field] < $b[$sort_field]) ? ($this->backwards ? 1 : -1) : ($this->backwards ? -1 : 1);
    }
    return 0;
  }

  function stringCompare($a, $b) {
    foreach($this->sort_fields as $sort_field) {
      $cmp_result = strcasecmp($a[$sort_field], $b[$sort_field]);
      if ($cmp_result == 0) continue;

      return ($this->backwards ? -$cmp_result : $cmp_result);
    }
    return 0;
  }
}

/////////////////////
// usage examples

// some starting data
$start_data = array(
  array('first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Smith', 'age' => 10),
  array('first_name' => 'Joe', 'last_name' => 'Smith', 'age' => 11),
  array('first_name' => 'Jake', 'last_name' => 'Xample', 'age' => 9),
);

// sort by last_name, then first_name
$sorter = new Sorter();
print_r($sorter->sort($start_data, 'last_name', 'first_name'));

// sort by first_name, then last_name
$sorter = new Sorter();
print_r($sorter->sort($start_data, 'first_name', 'last_name'));

// sort by last_name, then first_name (backwards)
$sorter = new Sorter();
$sorter->backwards = true;
print_r($sorter->sort($start_data, 'last_name', 'first_name'));

// sort numerically by age
$sorter = new Sorter();
$sorter->numeric = true;
print_r($sorter->sort($start_data, 'age'));
```

Comment: Does this only work with associative arrays?

Comment: yes - associative arrays only.  Now that I look at it, it is not the right solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "Usort" function is your answer.
http://php.net/usort

Comment: I have downvoted you because of your failure to provide a solution with explanation and examples to the original question. Update your response and I will reverse my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Before I could get the TableSorter class to run I had came up with a function based on what [Shinhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18219/shinhan) had provided.

```
function sort2d_bycolumn($array, $column, $method, $has_header)
  {
  if ($has_header)  $header = array_shift($array);
  foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $narray[$key]  = $row[$column]; 
    }
  array_multisort($narray, $method, $array);
  if ($has_header) array_unshift($array, $header);
  return $array;
  }
```

- $array is the MD Array you want to sort.
- $column is the column you wish to sort by.
- $method is how you want the sort performed, such as SORT_DESC
- $has_header is set to true if the first row contains header values that you don't want sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several popular array_multisort() and usort() answers and none of them worked for me.  The data just gets jumbled and the code is unreadable.  Here's a quick a dirty solution.  WARNING: Only use this if you're sure a rogue delimiter won't come back to haunt you later!

Let's say each row in your multi array looks like: name, stuff1, stuff2:

```
// Sort by name, pull the other stuff along for the ride
foreach ($names_stuff as $name_stuff) {
    // To sort by stuff1, that would be first in the contatenation
    $sorted_names[] = $name_stuff[0] .','. name_stuff[1] .','. $name_stuff[2];
}
sort($sorted_names, SORT_STRING);
```

Need your stuff back in alphabetical order?

```
foreach ($sorted_names as $sorted_name) {
    $name_stuff = explode(',',$sorted_name);
    // use your $name_stuff[0] 
    // use your $name_stuff[1] 
    // ... 
}
```

Yeah, it's dirty.  But super easy, won't make your head explode.