# Sort an array of associative arrays by column value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Given this array:

```
$inventory = array(

   array("type"=>"fruit", "price"=>3.50),
   array("type"=>"milk", "price"=>2.90),
   array("type"=>"pork", "price"=>5.43),

);
```

I would like to sort `$inventory`'s elements by price to get:

```
$inventory = array(

   array("type"=>"pork", "price"=>5.43),
   array("type"=>"fruit", "price"=>3.50),
   array("type"=>"milk", "price"=>2.90),

);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: Why not simply restructure your input array so that the `price` column comes first and `type` comes second?  This way, you can just call `rsort()`. https://3v4l.org/2meqs

Comment: [Sorting canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17364127/2943403)

Answer (score 801, accepted):

You are right, the function you're looking for is [`array_multisort()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

Here's an example taken straight from the manual and adapted to your case:

```
$price = array();
foreach ($inventory as $key => $row)
{
    $price[$key] = $row['price'];
}
array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $inventory);
```

As of PHP 5.5.0 you can use `array_column()` instead of that foreach:

```
$price = array_column($inventory, 'price');

array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $inventory);
```

Comment: Though this is definitely more expensive than the alternatives.

Comment: More expensive? That's weird, on my machine (running PHP 5.3.1-dev) array_multisort() is a few percent faster on small arrays and up to 100 times faster on big arrays (100+ elements)

Comment: It shouldn't require any change to work with numeric keys. If you're hitting a bug or weird behaviour related to numeric keys, post it as a new question.

Comment: array_multisort has a big problem: it doesn't maintain the original key.

Comment: @machineaddict it does maintain the associative keys.

Comment: @MatejSvajger: quote from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) `Associative (string) keys will be maintained, but numeric keys will be re-indexed. `

Comment: @machineaddict hence the associative keys remain intact, or am i reading this wrong?

Comment: @MatejSvajger: only the string keys will remain intact

Comment: I think you meant array_multisort($inventory, SORT_DESC, $price);

Comment: if you want to maintain numeric index then you're not sorting them lol. to do this however simply do this: `for($i=0,$L=count($myArray); $i<$L; $i++) $newArray[$i +''] = $myArray[$i];  ` then you can sort it as an associative array and use the sorted $newArray as follows to map back to your original:  `foreach($newArray as $k => $v) greatFunction( $myArray[ ($k + 0) ] );` the function will get called with the element in proper order, but refering to the original indexed array

Comment: @Matthieu No, the order written in this answer is correct and the order you suggest would not sort the `$inventory` array. Test it yourself - it's trivial to do so.

Comment: This works. I was wondering how to give the outer index values (for many records) but it figures it out by itself; just give the name in __array_column__ then use __array_multisort__. As for index preservation, numerics are reset but others are maintained.

Answer (score 514):

#### PHP 7+

As of PHP 7, this can be done concisely using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) that uses the [spaceship operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator) to compare elements.

You can do an ascending sort like this:

```
usort($inventory, function ($item1, $item2) {
    return $item1['price'] <=> $item2['price'];
});
```

Or a descending sort like this:

```
usort($inventory, function ($item1, $item2) {
    return $item2['price'] <=> $item1['price'];
});
```

To understand how this works, note that `usort` takes a user-provided comparison function that must behave as follows (from the docs):

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

And note also that `<=>`, the spaceship operator,

> returns 0 if both operands are equal, 1 if the left is greater, and -1 if the right is greater

which is exactly what `usort` needs. In fact, almost the entire justification given for adding `<=>` to the language in https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator is that it

> makes writing ordering callbacks for use with `usort()` easier

---

#### PHP 5.3+

PHP 5.3 introduced anonymous functions, but doesn't yet have the spaceship operator. We can still use `usort` to sort our array, but it's a little more verbose and harder to understand:

```
usort($inventory, function ($item1, $item2) {
    if ($item1['price'] == $item2['price']) return 0;
    return $item1['price'] < $item2['price'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Note that although it's fairly common for comparators dealing with integer values to just return the difference of the values, like `$item2['price'] - $item1['price']`, we *can't* safely do that in this case. This is because the prices are floating point numbers in the question asker's example, but the comparison function we pass to `usort` has to return integers for `usort` to work properly:

> Returning ***non-integer*** values from the comparison function, such as float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as equal.

This is an important trap to bear in mind when using `usort` in PHP 5.x! [My original version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19454643/1) made this mistake and yet I accrued ten upvotes over thousands of views apparently without anybody noticing the serious bug. The ease with which lackwits like me can screw up comparator functions is *precisely* the reason that the easier-to-use spaceship operator was added to the language in PHP 7.

Comment: Sorry, but this approach deletes the string keys from associative arrays. "uasort" function should be used, instead.

Comment: @DotMat Interesting - I didn't know about [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php). After looking at the docs, though, this answer is still correct *in this case*. In the OP's example, the array to be sorted has sequential numeric indexes rather than string indexes, so `usort` is more appropriate. Using `uasort` on a sequentially-indexed array will result in a sorted array which is not ordered by its numeric indexes, such that the first element seen in a `foreach` loop is not `$your_array[0]`, which is unlikely to be desirable behaviour.

Comment: for infos, using numeric keys (which are article ids) extrated from a json file , and php 8x , i used uasort and the spaceship to not modify the key value (so value sticks to their original article's id) . See https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php to find out, whoever needs it, which Maintains key association .  Thanks for this answer that was really usefull.

Answer (score 163):

While others have correctly suggested the use of [`array_multisort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), for some reason no answer seems to acknowledge the existence of [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), which can greatly simplify the solution. So my suggestion would be:

```
array_multisort(array_column($inventory, 'price'), SORT_DESC, $inventory);
```

If you want **Case Insensitive Sort** on strings, you can use `SORT_NATURAL|SORT_FLAG_CASE`

```
array_multisort(array_column($inventory, 'key_name'), SORT_DESC, SORT_NATURAL|SORT_FLAG_CASE, $inventory);
```

Comment: For some reason I was not able to make it work with strings having lower/upper letters. Even using the SORT_FLAG_CASE. The following worked for string comparision for me: array_multisort( array_map(strtolower, array_column($ipr_projects, 'Name')), SORT_ASC, $ipr_projects);

Comment: Working well PHP 7.4

Answer (score 46):

Since your array elements are arrays themselves with string keys, your best bet is to define a custom comparison function.  It's pretty quick and easy to do.  Try this:

```
function invenDescSort($item1,$item2)
{
    if ($item1['price'] == $item2['price']) return 0;
    return ($item1['price'] < $item2['price']) ? 1 : -1;
}
usort($inventory,'invenDescSort');
print_r($inventory);
```

Produces the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => pork
            [price] => 5.43
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => fruit
            [price] => 3.5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => milk
            [price] => 2.9
        )

)
```

Comment: Combining with some of the other comments here (uasort and inline anonymous functions), you get this one-liner: `uasort( $inventory, function ($a, $b) { if ( $a==$b ) return 0; else return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1; });`

Comment: @AlanPorter `usort` seems more appropriate than `uasort` for sorting an array with sequential numeric keys. Ending up with an array where the first element is at index `1` and the second element is at index `0` is weird behavior and a sure trap for people who aren't familiar with the details of PHP's arrays; `usort` gives you the output you'd intuitively expect.

Answer (score 30):

I ended on this:

```
function sort_array_of_array(&$array, $subfield)
{
    $sortarray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $row)
    {
        $sortarray[$key] = $row[$subfield];
    }

    array_multisort($sortarray, SORT_ASC, $array);
}
```

Just call the function, passing the array and the name of the field of the second level array.
Like:

```
sort_array_of_array($inventory, 'price');
```

Comment: It is unnecessary to preserve the `$key` in the temporary `$sortarray`.  This answer can be reduced to one line without the custom function declarationa and the explicit direction constant usage. `array_multisort(array_column($array, $subfield), $array);`

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) with anonymous function, e.g.

```
usort($inventory, function ($a, $b) { return strnatcmp($a['price'], $b['price']); });
```

Comment: Versions PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7 for those of you like me that really wanted this to work for them..

Comment: Remarkable that [`strnatcmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php), meant for comparing strings, seems to work fine here. Apparently the "natural order" it implements includes sorting numerical strings numerically rather than lexically.

Comment: The spaceship operator performs the same kind of comparison without the iterated function calls.

Answer (score 17):

From [*Sort an array of associative arrays by value of given key in php*](https://qoify.com/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-given-key-in-php):

by using usort (http://php.net/usort) , we can sort an array in ascending and descending order. just we need to create a function and pass it as parameter in usort. As per below example used greater than for ascending order if we passed less than condition then it's sort in descending order.
Example :

```
$array = array(
  array('price'=>'1000.50','product'=>'test1'),
  array('price'=>'8800.50','product'=>'test2'),
  array('price'=>'200.0','product'=>'test3')
);

function cmp($a, $b) {
  return $a['price'] > $b['price'];
}

usort($array, "cmp");
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 200.0
            [product] => test3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 1000.50
            [product] => test1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 8800.50
            [product] => test2
        )
  )
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Comment: -1; the `cmp` function here is wrong. It's supposed to return *"an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second"* but instead returns `true` or `false`. It seems, remarkably, to nonetheless work - perhaps because the current implementation of `usort` and friends treats the "less than" and "equal to" cases identically - but don't count on it carrying on working in future PHP versions. If they try to make sorts be stable (i.e. not move around equal elements unnecessarily), this will break.

Comment: Also, `usort` would be more appropriate than `uasort` here, since `uasort` preserves the association between keys and values which is confusing and unexpected when deaing with a sequential numerical array. For instance, the indexes of `$array` above after calling `uasort` are 2, 0, and 1, in that order. Unless you for some reason want that, you'll probably be more comfortable using `usort`, which reindexes the array as well as reordering it.

Comment: in php7+: in the cmp function one should use the <=> 'spaceship' operator

Answer (score 14):

```
$inventory = 
    array(array("type"=>"fruit", "price"=>3.50),
          array("type"=>"milk", "price"=>2.90),
          array("type"=>"pork", "price"=>5.43),
          );

function pricesort($a, $b) {
  $a = $a['price'];
  $b = $b['price'];
  if ($a == $b)
    return 0;
  return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($inventory, "pricesort");
// uksort($inventory, "pricesort");

print("first: ".$inventory[0]['type']."\n\n");
// for usort(): prints milk (item with lowest price)
// for uksort(): prints fruit (item with key 0 in the original $inventory)

// foreach prints the same for usort and uksort.
foreach($inventory as $i){
  print($i['type'].": ".$i['price']."\n");
}
```

outputs:

```
first: pork

pork: 5.43
fruit: 3.5
milk: 2.9
```

Answer (score 8):

```
/**
 * Sorts an associative array by a specific key and direction.
 *
 * @param array $array The associative array to sort.
 * @param string $key The key to sort by.
 * @param string $direction The sort direction ("ASC" for ascending, "DESC" for descending).
 * @return array The sorted associative array.
 */
function sortAssociativeArrayByKey($array, $key, $direction) {
    usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($key, $direction) {
        $comparison = $a[$key] <=> $b[$key];
        return ($direction === 'DESC') ? -$comparison : $comparison;
    });
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I use `uasort` like this

```
<?php
$users = [
    [
        'username' => 'joe',
        'age' => 11
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'rakoto',
        'age' => 21
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'rabe',
        'age' => 17
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'fy',
        'age' => 19
    ],    
];


uasort($users, function ($item, $compare) {
    return $item['username'] >= $compare['username']; 
});

var_dump($users);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stack Overflow because they do a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Furthermore, suggesting techniques that were already provided years earlier does NOT help researchers -- in fact, it wastes their research time because they end up reading more content but gain no new information.

Comment: No modern PHP applications should be returning a boolean type value in the custom callback; an integer is expected.

Answer (score 7):

**As of PHP 7.4, you can use arrow function:**

```
usort(
    $inventory, 
    fn(array $a, array $b): int => $b['price'] <=> $a['price']
);
```

Code ([demo](https://3v4l.org/fHTXF)):

```php
$inventory = [
    ['type' => 'fruit', 'price' => 3.50],
    ['type' => 'milk',  'price' => 2.90],
    ['type' => 'pork',  'price' => 5.43],
];

usort(
    $inventory, 
    fn(array $a, array $b): int => $b['price'] <=> $a['price']
);

print_r($inventory);
```

(condensed) Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array ([type] => pork,  [price] => 5.43)
    [1] => Array ([type] => fruit, [price] => 3.5)
    [2] => Array ([type] => milk,  [price] => 2.9)
)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Was tested on 100 000 records:**
Time in seconds(calculated by funciton microtime).
*Only for unique values on sorting key positions.*

**Solution of function of @Josh Davis:**
*Spended time*: 1.5768740177155

**Mine solution:**
*Spended time*: 0.094044923782349

**Solution:**

```
function SortByKeyValue($data, $sortKey, $sort_flags=SORT_ASC)
{
    if (empty($data) or empty($sortKey)) return $data;

    $ordered = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        $ordered[$value[$sortKey]] = $value;

    ksort($ordered, $sort_flags);

    return array_values($ordered); *// array_values() added for identical result with multisort*
}
```

Comment: The requirement for unique sort keys is sort of a deal breaker, though. If you have unique sort values that can be keys, it begs the question: why not simply construct the array with those keys to begin with? In the OP's scenario, it is difficult to imagine that two items with the same price would be **impossible**. That in mind, using this solution would cause items from the array to mysteriously and silently disappear from the sorted result set.

Comment: @Chris Baker, you are right. This works only for unique values. But this solution works very fast, so speed was the reason of make and use it. At the moment may be it is not actual, need to test it with PHP 7.1.x.

Comment: `array_column()` can do what the `foreach()` is doing.  If there are performance improvements by making key comparisons, it needs to be acknowledged that this answer doubles the memory consumption by populating the new array and as Chris Baker noted, if duplicate values are encountered in the identifying column, then whole rows will be lost.  Also, if assigning keys that PHP will truncate (using a float type value as the key) then there may be side effects like lost data.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
$prices = array_column($inventory, 'price');
array_multisort($prices, SORT_DESC, $inventory);
print_r($inventory);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Comment: Please never duplicate the advice of previous posts (especially on the same page).  This needlessly bloats Stack Overflow and wastes researchers' time.

Answer (score 3):

This function is re-usable:

```
function usortarr(&$array, $key, $callback = 'strnatcasecmp') {
    uasort($array, function($a, $b) use($key, $callback) {
        return call_user_func($callback, $a[$key], $b[$key]);
    });
}
```

It works well on string values by default, but you'll have to sub the callback for a [number comparison function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2852621/65387) if all your values are numbers.

Comment: You call this `usortarr` but then call `uasort` instead of `usort`; perhaps a bit confusing. The latter is - in the case of a sequential array with numerical indexes, like the one exhibited in the question - probably what you actually want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that I found long ago and cleaned up a bit. This works great, and can be quickly changed to accept objects as well.

```
/**
 * A method for sorting arrays by a certain key:value.
 * SortByKey is the key you wish to sort by
 * Direction can be ASC or DESC.
 *
 * @param $array
 * @param $sortByKey
 * @param $sortDirection
 * @return array
 */
private function sortArray($array, $sortByKey, $sortDirection) {

    $sortArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
        $tempArray[] = strtolower( $value[ $sortByKey ] );
    }

    if($sortDirection=='ASC'){ asort($tempArray ); }
        else{ arsort($tempArray ); }

    foreach ( $tempArray as $key => $temp ){
        $sortArray[] = $array[ $key ];
    }

    return $sortArray;

}
```

to change the method to sort objects simply change the following line:

`$tempArray[] = strtolower( $value[ $sortByKey ] );`
to
`$tempArray[] = strtolower( $value->$sortByKey );`

To run the method simply do

`sortArray($inventory,'price','ASC');`

Comment: This approach works, but is a fair bit less concise than either Josh Davis's answer (with `array_multisort`) or mine (with `usort`) and seems to offer no advantages over them in exchange.

Comment: I don't see myself ever having a need for such a script in a professional project.  See also [Case Insensitively Sort a Multidimensional PHP Array using array_multisort()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27141328/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

Many people are searching for a way to do this with Laravel and ending up here. Also, some Laravel questions are getting closed due to duplicates to this question.
Hence, I shared an easy way to perform it with Laravel collect() method.

```
$inventory = collect($inventory)->sortBy('price')->toArray();
```

For Descending order

```
$inventory = collect($inventory)->sortBy('price')->reverse()->toArray();
```

Or,

```
$inventory = collect($inventory)->('price')->reverse()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try to define your own comparison function and then use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Comment: Yes. I'll do that if I can't find a solution. I'm pretty sure there are some weird parameters you can add to one of the sorts to accomplish this. Thanks for your thoughts though!

Comment: In comparison to the other answers posted here, this answer looks more like a "hint" that should be a comment under the question instead of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Just in one line custom function
function cmp($a, $b)
{
return (float) $a['price'] < (float)$b['price'];
}
@uasort($inventory, "cmp");
print_r($inventory);

//result

Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [type] => pork
        [price] => 5.43
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [type] => fruit
        [price] => 3.5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [type] => milk
        [price] => 2.9
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Complete Dynamic Function**
I jumped here for associative array sorting and found this amazing function on http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php. This function is very dynamic that sort in ascending and descending order with specified key.

Simple function to sort an array by a specific key. Maintains index association

```
<?php

function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC)
{
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
            break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}

$people = array(
    12345 => array(
        'id' => 12345,
        'first_name' => 'Joe',
        'surname' => 'Bloggs',
        'age' => 23,
        'sex' => 'm'
    ),
    12346 => array(
        'id' => 12346,
        'first_name' => 'Adam',
        'surname' => 'Smith',
        'age' => 18,
        'sex' => 'm'
    ),
    12347 => array(
        'id' => 12347,
        'first_name' => 'Amy',
        'surname' => 'Jones',
        'age' => 21,
        'sex' => 'f'
    )
);

print_r(array_sort($people, 'age', SORT_DESC)); // Sort by oldest first
print_r(array_sort($people, 'surname', SORT_ASC)); // Sort by surname
```

Comment: `if (count($array) > 0) {` is unneeded before the `foreach()`.  Is this script over-engineered?  I'm not sure I'd use something like this versus a native `array_multisort()` or `usort()` call.

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr1 = array(

    array('id'=>1,'name'=>'aA','cat'=>'cc'),
    array('id'=>2,'name'=>'aa','cat'=>'dd'),
    array('id'=>3,'name'=>'bb','cat'=>'cc'),
    array('id'=>4,'name'=>'bb','cat'=>'dd')
);

$result1 = array_msort($arr1, array('name'=>SORT_DESC);

$result2 = array_msort($arr1, array('cat'=>SORT_ASC);

$result3 = array_msort($arr1, array('name'=>SORT_DESC, 'cat'=>SORT_ASC));


function array_msort($array, $cols)
{
    $colarr = array();
    foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
    $colarr[$col] = array();
    foreach ($array as $k => $row) { $colarr[$col]['_'.$k] = strtolower($row[$col]); }
}

$eval = 'array_multisort(';

foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
    $eval .= '$colarr[\''.$col.'\'],'.$order.',';
}

$eval = substr($eval,0,-1).');';
eval($eval);
$ret = array();
foreach ($colarr as $col => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $k = substr($k,1);
        if (!isset($ret[$k])) $ret[$k] = $array[$k];
        $ret[$k][$col] = $array[$k][$col];
    }
}
return $ret;


}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: [Case Insensitively Sort a Multidimensional PHP Array using array_multisort()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27141328/2943403)

Answer (score -1):

If you need to sort an array of strings with different cases, this will change the sorting array values to lowercase.

```
$data = [
    [
        'name' => 'jack',
        'eyeColor' => 'green'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Amy',
        'eyeColor' => 'brown'
    ],
    [   
        'name' => 'Cody',
        'eyeColor' => 'blue'
    ] 
];
function toLowerCase($a) { return strtolower($a); }
$sortArray = array_map("toLowerCase",array_column($data, 'name'));
array_multisort($sortArray, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

Comment: [Case Insensitively Sort a Multidimensional PHP Array using array_multisort()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27141328/2943403)

Answer (score -1):

This function works 100% on all major versions of PHP and it is tested with **PHP5**, **PHP7**, **PHP8**.

```
    function sort_my_array($array, $order_by, $order)
    {
        switch ($order) {
            case "asc":
                usort($array, function ($first, $second) use ($order_by) {
                    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0') >= 0) {
                        return $first[$order_by] <=> $second[$order_by];
                    } else {
                        $array_cmp = strcmp($first[$order_by], $second[$order_by]);
                        return $array_cmp ;
                    }
                });
                break;
            case "desc":
                usort($certificates, function ($first, $second) use ($order_by) {
                    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0') >= 0) {
                        return $first[$order_by] <=> $second[$order_by];
                    } else {
                        $array_cmp = strcmp($first[$order_by], $second[$order_by]);
                        return -$array_cmp ;
                    }
                });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

Comment: Too much redundant code. If `$order === 'desc'`, then multiply the returned value by `-1`.  `default` doesn't need a `break`. An empty `default` is pointless.  The version comparison will not change during script execution, so it makes no sense to check it on each iteration.

Answer (score -6):

try this:

```
asort($array_to_sort, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

for reference see this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

see various sort flags here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: this won't work for multidimensional arrays, but just helped me out for another problem, thanks :)

Comment: This can't be used to sort a list of dictionaries by a particular dictionary key, and hence doesn't answer the question posed.