# how to sort arrays in php

Tags: php, sorting, dns

I need to sort the results from a dns query first by priority, and then within the records that have the biggest priority values, i want to sort by the lowest weight. 
So for example:

Let's say I get the following data back from my dns_get_record() query:

```
 { 
    [0]=> array(8) 
    { 
        ["host"]=> string(27) "_sip._udp.test.123.test.net" 
        ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" 
        ["ttl"]=> int(360) 
        ["type"]=> string(3) "SRV" 
        ["pri"]=> int(10) 
        ["weight"]=> int(100) 
        ["port"]=> int(5060) 
        ["target"]=> string(22) "mysip1.123.test.net" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(8) 
    { 
        ["host"]=> string(27) "_sip._udp.test.123.test.net" 
        ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" 
        ["ttl"]=> int(360) 
        ["type"]=> string(3) "SRV" 
        ["pri"]=> int(20) 
        ["weight"]=> int(100) 
        ["port"]=> int(5060) 
        ["target"]=> string(23) "mysip2.123.test.net" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(8) 
    { 
        ["host"]=> string(27) "_sip._udp.test.123.test.net" 
        ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" 
        ["ttl"]=> int(360) 
        ["type"]=> string(3) "SRV" 
        ["pri"]=> int(20) 
        ["weight"]=> int(200) 
        ["port"]=> int(5060) 
        ["target"]=> string(23) "mysip3.123.test.net" 
    } 
}
```

What I want to end up with is this:

```
 { 
    [0]=> array(8) 
    { 
        ["host"]=> string(27) "_sip._udp.test.123.test.net" 
        ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" 
        ["ttl"]=> int(360) 
        ["type"]=> string(3) "SRV" 
        ["pri"]=> int(20) 
        ["weight"]=> int(100) 
        ["port"]=> int(5060) 
        ["target"]=> string(23) "mysip2.123.test.net" 
    } 

    [1]=> array(8) 
    { 
        ["host"]=> string(27) "_sip._udp.test.123.test.net" 
        ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" 
        ["ttl"]=> int(360) 
        ["type"]=> string(3) "SRV" 
        ["pri"]=> int(20) 
        ["weight"]=> int(200) 
        ["port"]=> int(5060) 
        ["target"]=> string(23) "mysip3.123.test.net" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(8) 
    { 
        ["host"]=> string(27) "_sip._udp.test.123.test.net" 
        ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" 
        ["ttl"]=> int(360) 
        ["type"]=> string(3) "SRV" 
        ["pri"]=> int(10) 
        ["weight"]=> int(100) 
        ["port"]=> int(5060) 
        ["target"]=> string(22) "mysip1.123.test.net" 
    } 

}
```

Notice that I now have:
1.  The priorities sorted from biggest number to smallest....
2.  Within the higher priority records, the one with the smaller value in weight is listed first.

**Code**

I have written code to do the first sort, where items with the higher priority values are at the top.  This is what my code looks like so far:

```
 $results=dns_get_record("test.123.test.net", DNS_NAPTR);
 $answer = $results[0]["replacement"];
 $sipservers = dns_get_record($answer,DNS_SRV);
```

And then to sort:

```
    private function comp($a, $b) {
            if ($a['pri'] == $b['pri']) {
                    return $a['weight'] - $b['weight'];
            }
            return strcmp($a['pri'], $b['weight']);
    }

usort($sipservers, 'comp');
echo("<BR><BR> after sort: <BR><BR>");
var_dump($sipservers);
```

But it's sorted ascending for fields.  This sort is based on a post I found here:  [PHP usort sorting multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260343/php-usort-sorting-multiple-fields)

I'm still trying to review this to better understand what it's doing.  I've clearly not adapted it properly for my use case.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) should do the trick.

Comment: @AndreiP, can you expand with an example  on how i can change my current use of that function or use it again?

Comment: Ah I think I just need to reverse a- b to b- a.  Will try after lunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake on my part. 
I thought I did, but I missed swapping around the following:

```
return $a['weight'] - $b['weight'];
```

That is now:

```
return $b['weight'] - $a['weight'];
```

Thanks.