# Array element sorting using multiple keys inside the element - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I have and array converted to JSON like so:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sally",
        "nick_name": "sal",
        "availability": "0",
        "is_fav": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "David",
        "nick_name": "dav07",
        "availability": "0",
        "is_fav": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Zen",
        "nick_name": "zen",
        "availability": "1",
        "is_fav": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Jackson",
        "nick_name": "jack",
        "availability": "1",
        "is_fav": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Rohit",
        "nick_name": "rod",
        "availability": "0",
        "is_fav": "0"
    },

]
```

I want to sort the whole array in following sequence based on values of `is_fav`, `availability`, and `nick_name`:

`[ is_fav:1 availability:1 ]`
`[ is_fav:1 availability:0 ]`
`[ is_fav:0 availability:1 ]`
`[ is_fav:0 availability:0 ]`

Where in each of those conditions the elements are ordered alphabetically using `nick_name`

So the final array in the above example would look like

```
[
    {
        "name": "Jackson",
        "nick_name": "jack",
        "availability": "1",
        "is_fav": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "David",
        "nick_name": "dav07",
        "availability": "0",
        "is_fav": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Zen",
        "nick_name": "zen",
        "availability": "1",
        "is_fav": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Rohit",
        "nick_name": "rod",
        "availability": "0",
        "is_fav": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sally",
        "nick_name": "sal",
        "availability": "0",
        "is_fav": "0"
    },
]
```

Comment: ok you want to achieve sorting, but what have you tried, provide some code that you tried.

Comment: From where you were getting this data if you're getting it from DB you can simply achieve it using MySQL

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3233009

Comment: also if you made this via `sql query` then update your query so that you can get proper format automatically.

Comment: @SandeepBiradar I was looking at `array_multisort` but realised I should manipulate the array before hand but could not figure out exactly how to break the array to feed into the method.

Comment: @Uchiha I have queried the resulting array from my own database.

Comment: Then simply use `order by is_fav desc, availability desc`

Comment: @Uchiha The problem I have obtained this from multiple tables and in multiple steps. It is not one single query. I am already getting a list of users from one API and I am running two more methods to check availability and isFavorite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
    $isFav[$key] = $row['is_fav'];
    $avail[$key] = $row['availability'];
    $names[$key] = $row['nick_name'];
}

// Sort the data with isFav descending, avail descending
// Add $arr as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($isFav, SORT_DESC, $avail, SORT_DESC, $names, SORT_ASC, $arr);
```

You can see it in action [here (3v4l.org)](https://3v4l.org/f6sMQ)

Comment: This soulution seems to work for the order or `is_fav` and `availability`. But when in run it on the acual data, there is no sorting based on the `nick_name`.

Comment: I still dont have correct order with `nick_name` :( I need ASC so I have changed to SORT_ASC. How is `null` treated while sorting? The values of `availability` is either `NULL` or `1`

Comment: OH! My Bad. I didnt know it was case sensitive sort. Very Sorry. It works perfect.!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function of PHP like as

```
usort($arr,function($a,$b){
    $c = $b['is_fav'] - $a['is_fav'];
    $c .= $b['availability'] - $a['availability'];
    $c .= strcmp($a['nick_name'],$b['nick_name']);
    return $c;
});
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
usort($arr, function ($item1, $item2) {
    // your condition
    if ($item1['is_fav'] && !$item2['is_fav']) return 1;
    if (!$item1['is_fav'] && $item2['is_fav']) return -1;
    if ($item1['availability'] > $item2['availability']) return 1;
    if ($item1['availability'] < $item2['availability']) return -1;
    return 0;
});
$data = json_encode($arr);
```