# PHP sort array by key in 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

In a Php i have an Array like this.

```
$task_array = array(
    '0' => array('task_name' => 'tsk3','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter3'),
    '1' => array('task_name' => 'tsk1','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter1'),
    '2' => array('task_name' => 'tsk2','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter2'),
    '3' => array('task_name' => 'tsk6','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter6'),
    '4' => array('task_name' => 'tsk4','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter3'),
    '5' => array('task_name' => 'tsk6','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter4'),
    '6' => array('task_name' => 'tsk6','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter7')
);
```

What i want to do is sorting by `task_chapter_name` but one more condition is there that if `task_chapter_name` value is same then next sorting should `task_name` wise.

**Required Output**

```
$task_array = array(
    '0' => array('task_name' => 'tsk1','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter1'),
    '1' => array('task_name' => 'tsk2','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter2'),
    '2' => array('task_name' => 'tsk3','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter3'),
    '3' => array('task_name' => 'tsk4','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter3'),
    '4' => array('task_name' => 'tsk6','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter4'),
    '5' => array('task_name' => 'tsk6','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter6'),
    '6' => array('task_name' => 'tsk6','task_chapter_name' => 'chapter7')
);
```

My Question is Marked as Duplicate but here i want to inform you that i have priorities sorting with the multidimensional array,  My first priority was to sort by `task_chapter_name` now if i am getting same values in `task_chapter_name` then it should be sort with `task_name`.

Comment: Did this before... hang on.

Comment: Okay . .  waittting,. , ,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3233009/3355243

Comment: @Pavlin , cant you see that i have multiple keys to sort with some priorities ? ?

Comment: My bad, use `array_multisort`, as brilliantly suggested by Linesofcode.

Comment: used the solution given by @Aaron, which is easier ,  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($task_array as $key => $row) {
    $taskChapterName[$key]  = $row['task_chapter_name'];
    $taskName[$key] = $row['task_name'];
}
array_multisort($taskChapterName, SORT_ASC, $taskName, SORT_ASC, $task_array);
```

Comment: its returning 1   :-(

Comment: @PunitGajjar Check `$task_array` after running this code.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the columns and sort on them in order, sorting the original array last.  Obviously you can use `SORT_ASC` or `SORT_DESC` for the different arrays for different orders:

```
array_multisort(array_column($task_array, 'task_chapter_name'),
                array_column($task_array, 'task_name'),
                $task_array);
```

PHP >= 5.5.0 is needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php).  Or you can loop through and build arrays to use in the sort above:

```
foreach($task_array as $val) {
    $chap[] = $val['task_chapter_name'];
    $task[] = $val['task_name'];
}
```