# PHP Sorting Array Using usort() Not Working

Tags: php

I have this array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => lm81-1527799632244
            [robo] => C4
            [price] => 53.83600000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => lm81-1527799632244
            [robo] => RE
            [price] => 53.83600000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => lm81-1527799632244
            [robo] => C4
            [price] => 0.09188900
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => lm81-1527799632244
            [robo] => RE
            [price] => 0.09188900
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => lm81-1527799632244
            [robo] => C4
            [price] => 584.80000000
        )

)
```

and I'm expecting result like this (sort by robo DESC) :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => lm81-1527799632244
            [robo] => RE
            [price] => 53.83600000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => lm81-1527799632244
            [robo] => RE
            [price] => 0.09188900
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => lm81-1527799632244
            [robo] => C4
            [price] => 53.83600000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => lm81-1527799632244
            [robo] => C4
            [price] => 0.09188900
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => lm81-1527799632244
            [robo] => C4
            [price] => 584.80000000
        )

)
```

and I already done this :

```
    usort($dc_array_process, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['robo'] - $b['robo'];
    });
```

but my array still not in DESC order. any idea what did I do wrong?

Comment: To sort descending, use `$b <=> $a` instead of `$a <=> $b`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647220/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sorting `string` values, you should use `strcmp`

```
usort($dc_array_process, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['robo'], $b['robo']);
});
```

or

```
usort($dc_array_process, function($a, $b) {
    return -strcmp($a['robo'], $b['robo']);  //negative to reverse
});
```

document:

> int strcmp ( string $str1 , string $str2 )
>
> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than
>   str2, and 0 if they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Because arithmetic `-` causes values to be converted to **int**.

```
usort($dc_array_process, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['robo'], $b['robo']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the manual](http://php.net/usort), the comparison function passed into usort must…

> return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero

…for the order to be correctly determined. As the values you're attempting to sort are strings, the minus operation you're using therefore won't work.

Try using strcmp in the return…

```
return strcmp( $a['robo'], $b['robo'] );
```