# Sorting Multi Dimensional Array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have below array with me:

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
     ['sort'] => 1
     ['ques'] => 'Zing order'
    )
[1] => Array(
     ['sort'] => 1
     ['ques'] => 'How stackoverflow works?'
    )
[2] => Array(
     ['sort'] => 2
     ['ques'] => 'What is PHP'
    )
)
```

What I want is:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
         ['sort'] => 1
         ['ques'] => 'How stackoverflow works?'
        )
    [1] => Array(
         ['sort'] => 1
         ['ques'] => 'Zing order'
        )
    [2] => Array(
         ['sort'] => 2
         ['ques'] => 'What is PHP'
        )
    )
```

Ideally, it should sort first with sort key and then alphabetically with ques key.

Comment: use usort function for this purpose

Comment: Use this answer that I just posted on the duplicate page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647220/2943403  It is the most modern and concise way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_multisort()` with the help of `array_column()`. So you have the power to set Sort Order now :)

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        'sort' => 1,
        'ques' => 'Zing order'
    ),
    array(
        'sort' => 1,
        'ques' => 'How stackoverflow works?'
    ),
    array(
        'sort' => 2,
        'ques' => 'What is PHP'
    )
);
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'sort'), SORT_ASC,
                array_column($array, 'ques'),      SORT_ASC,
                $array);
print_r($array);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/ofeZG

Comment: @mickmackusa thx, **Edited**