# PHP How to sort object(stdClass) containing object(stdClass) by two indices?

Tags: php, class, sorting, data-structures, stdout

I have the following data structure which needs to be sorted. First field to sort by is 'kategorie' and then 'order_by'. It's important that the keys of the objects remain unchanged, the urls get used in other parts of the code.

```
object(stdClass)#2 (31) {
      ["https://idp1.xxx/idp/shibboleth"]=>
      object(stdClass)#12 (4) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(19) "test"
        ["data"]=>
        string(39) "test"
        ["kategorie"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["order_by"]=>
        string(3) "200"
      }
      ["https://idp2.xxx/idp/shibboleth"]=>
      object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(52) "test"
        ["data"]=>
        string(60) "test"
        ["kategorie"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["order_by"]=>
        string(3) "110"
      } 
      ["https://idp3.xxx/idp/shibboleth"]=>
      object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(52) "test"
        ["data"]=>
        string(60) "test"
        ["kategorie"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["order_by"]=>
        string(3) "120"
      } ...
```

How it should look like:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (31) {
      ["https://idp3.xxx/idp/shibboleth"]=>
      object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(52) "test"
        ["data"]=>
        string(60) "test"
        ["kategorie"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["order_by"]=>
        string(3) "120"
      } 
      ["https://idp1.xxx/idp/shibboleth"]=>
      object(stdClass)#12 (4) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(19) "test"
        ["data"]=>
        string(39) "test"
        ["kategorie"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["order_by"]=>
        string(3) "200"
      }
      ["https://idp2.xxx/idp/shibboleth"]=>
      object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(52) "test"
        ["data"]=>
        string(60) "test"
        ["kategorie"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["order_by"]=>
        string(3) "110"
      } ...
```

Whats the easiest way to achive this? I just can't wrap my head around it...

Edit: usort doesn't work for stdClass Objects
This array_multisort doesn't work either

```
  array_multisort(array_column($entries, 'kategorie'), SORT_ASC,
                  array_column($entries, 'order_by'),      SORT_ASC,
                  $entries);
```

Edit2: Typcasting to array and the using the above multisort was the answer.

Comment: Title is wrong, it's not supposed to be sorted by indices, it's supposed to be sorted by object datafileds 'order_by' and 'kategorie'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort multidimensional array by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232965/sort-multidimensional-array-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: usort doesn't work for stdClass Objects and the array column answer doesn't do anything to my data

Comment: Well, and this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields
If your array comes from a `json_decode()` call, you pass `true` as 2nd parameter to get an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work as expected, because you're sorting by strings, so `"10" < "2"`. You can either convert these columns to numbers, or use `SORT_NUMERIC` flag:

```php
array_multisort(
    array_column($entries, 'kategorie'),
    SORT_NUMERIC,
    array_column($entries, 'order_by'),
    SORT_NUMERIC,
    $entries
);
```