# merge all arrays with same title

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-merge

i have this array in php json.

i have made it to sort array by first Characther.
but now i'm stuck on how to merge the data under the same title.

my response now is.

```
[
{
    "title": "A",
    "data": {
        "id": "317",
        "name": "Aesethetica"
    }
},
{
    "title": "A",
    "data": {
        "id": "318",
        "name": "Astonos"
    }
},
{
    "title": "B",
    "data": {
        "id": "320",
        "name": "Bourjois"
    }
},
{
    "title": "B",
    "data": {
        "id": "321",
        "name": "Bioderma"
    }
}
]
```

i need to merge all data under each same title.
something like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "A",
        "data": [
            {
            "id": "317",
            "name": "Aesethetica"
            },
            {
                "id": "318",
                "name": "Astonos"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "B",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "320",
                "name": "Bourjois"
            },
            {
                "id": "321",
                "name": "Bioderma"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

kindly help.
Thanks

---

i got this now:
i made this update.. but still not the needed result.

**this is my php code...**

```
$result = [];
                foreach ($data as $item) {
                    $firstLetter = substr($item['name'], 0, 1);
                    $result[] = [
                        'title' => $firstLetter = ctype_alnum($firstLetter) ? $firstLetter : '#',
                        'data' => $item
                    ];
                }

    foreach ($result as $key => $item) {
       $arr[$item['title']][$key] = $item;
    }
```

and this is the result.

```
{
    "A": [
        {
            "title": "A",
            "data": {
                "brand_id": "312",
                "brand_name": "Adidsa"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "A",
            "data": {
                "id": "314",
                "name": "Adio"
            }
        },
```

still can't find make the needed response..

Comment: @MarkusZeller i tried it, but i have issue with getting the "title" as index.

Comment: Why? Show your code.

Comment: @MarkusZeller i have update the answer.. plz check and advise

Comment: As easy as: [decode - sort - group - print](https://3v4l.org/UnU9M)  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647220/2943403) for details on sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not perfomance optimized, but shows a simple solution.

Collect all data grouped by title, then reformat the array to your expected result.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$collect = [];
foreach($array as $item) {
    $collect[$item['title']][] = $item['data'];
}
ksort($collect);

$titles = [];
foreach($collect as $title => $data) {
    $names = array_column($data, 'name');
    array_multisort($names, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $data);
    $titles[] = ['title' => $title, 'data' => $data];
}
```

`echo json_encode($titles, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` results in

```
[
    {
        "title": "A",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "317",
                "name": "Aesethetica"
            },
            {
                "id": "318",
                "name": "Astonos"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "B",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "321",
                "name": "Bioderma"
            },
            {
                "id": "320",
                "name": "Bourjois"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Amazing its working fine now, thank you very much.. one last question if i can ask... i need to sort the titles by "title"

A,B,C,D,E..... now it's not sorting alphabetically.

Comment: No problem. See updated answer. $title array is sorted by its key (A, B, C, ...) and the data by name.