# How to sort a multilevel arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I've read a file of names into an array from a .csv file using `fopen()`.  It gives me an array in the format shown below (I've eliminated most of the fields and trimmed it down to just a few entries for brevity.) I've tried referred to the PHP manual and numerous tutorials and code samples from the Internet and I can't make it work.

There are similar questions on stack exchange for sure, but they present solutions that aren't working for me.  I have a suspicion that they're due to the format or my array generated by `fopen()`, but I can't be sure.

Below is the array I see from `print_r()` in PHP.  I want to sort by last name, then first name.

```
Array 
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ed,
            [1] => Wilson,
            [2] => Chair
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bill,
            [1] => Adams,
            [2] => Convenor
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tom,
            [1] => Deschamps,
            [2] => Treasurer
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Wendell,
            [1] => Adams,
            [2] => Member
        )

)
```

Comment: _"Somehow the comparison function doesn't make sense to me"_ - see explanation in the duplicate. When you are working with `usort`, your callback function simply gets _two_ array elements passed in, and has to return a value depending on whether the first item is supposed to be "smaller", "equal" or "greater" in the sort order. You got two sort criteria here - so you check the first one first, and if the items are "equal" regarding that (both passed entries have the same last name), then you proceed with checking the next one.

Comment: I don't see any sorting code here to analyze, mostly just emotional appeals which distract from the technical question. Please share a [mcve] with your technical specification, input, expected/actual output, and some sort of transformation code (sorting code, or what have you). Avoid statements like "beating my head against the wall". Thanks.

Comment: My intention was not to make an emotional appeal but to point out that I've put effort into this and I'm not just asking for help right out of the gate, too lazy to look it up for myself.
You don't see sorting code because I don't know how to do that.  That's kind of the point. 
Another response - no longer visible - was basically just sarcasm, asking if I'd looked in the manual.
I don't seem to know how to navigate what's expected in a question here.

Comment: @sca This is a more narrow duplicate: [Sort multidimensional array by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647220/2943403)  It shows sortingby 2 columns, but it should be rather obvious how to reduce it to 2 sorting criteria.

Comment: @CBroe Machavity has asked for closers to avoid blanket-canonicals. Please be aware of [Rule proposal: Duplicate closure to roll-up questions is no longer allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427530/2943403)