# php usort() results in strange result

Tags: php, usort

I want to sort on field banner_id (int). But when running I get a strange result.

The result of this usort() is following:

> 101 - 204- 34 - 45 - 69 - etc.

I must get:

> 34 - 45 -69 - 101 - 204

```
function usort_reorder($a,$b){
    $orderby = (!empty($_REQUEST['orderby'])) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'banner_id'; 
    $order = (!empty($_REQUEST['order'])) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'asc'; 
    $result = strcmp($a[$orderby], $b[$orderby]); 
    return ($order==='asc') ? $result : -$result; 
}

usort($data, 'usort_reorder');
```

What to do to get this sort correct running. Means not only sorting the first digit but the whole digit. Now it only takes the first one.

Comment: `strcmp` compares values as strings, not numbers.

Comment: what kind of compare should i use here then?

Comment: If your field `$a[$orderby]` is numeric you can simply use `$result = $a[$orderby] > $b[$orderby];`.

Comment: I've found it. strnatcmp() is the solution

Comment: `$a[$orderby] <=> $b[$orderby]` if you’re on PHP 7.

Comment: @xander: Shouldn’t the comparison return `-1` if `$a < $b`?

Comment: @Ryan yes you're right, I was just thinking about sort order and not the return value of the compare function. By the way you can use the spaceship operator in PHP7 `$result = $a[$orderby] <=> $b[$orderby];` that would be correct (-1, 0 or 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sortScripts($a, $b)
{
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
}
```

Use `$b-$a` if you want the reversed order.

If the numbers in question exceed PHP's integer range, `return ($a < $b) ? -1 : (($a > $b) ? 1 : 0)` is more robust.

You can check this link for more understanding [strcmp equivelant for integers (intcmp) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852621/strcmp-equivelant-for-integers-intcmp-in-php)