# Modeling Ranking with NoSQL

Tags: database-design, nosql, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine, a Non-Relational Database (NoSQL). My question is, which is the best way to model a rank (ranking of players) using their scores?

For example, my players are:

```
Player { String name, int score}
```

I want to know the rank (position) for a player and also get the top 10 players, but I am unsure which is the best way.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/Rw1YzdxJqVo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modeling Ranking (scores) in Non Relational DataBase (NoSQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829923/modeling-ranking-scores-in-non-relational-database-nosql)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lib called google app engine ranklist.
http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-ranklist/

> Ranklist is a python library for Google App Engine that implements a
>   data structure for storing integer scores and quickly retrieving their
>   relative ranks.
>
> A very simple sample app is included in the source code, and can be
>   tried out at http://ranklist-example.appspot.com.