# How to sort an Array of Associative Arrays by a Value

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array:

```
$array = (
    array('name' => 'John' , 'total' => '33'),
    array('name' => 'Robert' , 'total' =>  '66'),
    array('name' => 'John' , 'total' => '22'),
)
```

I want to sort the arrays by the total.

So the output would be:

```
$array = (
    array('name' => 'Robert' , 'total' =>  '66')
    array('name' => 'John ' , 'total' => '33')
    array('name' => 'John' , 'total' => '22')
)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Check `array_multisort()`.

Comment: Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: Do you mean array('name'=>'Robert' , 'total'=>'66')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use array_multisort method

```
$arr = array(
    array('name' => 'John' , 'total' => '33'),
    array('name' => 'Robert' , 'total' =>  '66'),
    array('name' => 'John' , 'total' => '22'),
);

$total = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $row)
{
    $total[$key] = $row['total'];
}
array_multisort($total, SORT_DESC, $arr);
```

Comment: This is what i did and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use Multisort for this

```
$total = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $row)
{
    $total[$key] = $row['total'];
}
array_multisort($total, SORT_DESC, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I think you should better use arsort().
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function totalDescSort($item1, $item2)
{
    if ($item1['total'] == $item2['total']) return 0;
    return ($item1['total'] < $item2['total']) ? 1 : -1;
}
usort($array,'totalDescSort');
```

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597788/623400

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to order your array elements in a `DESCENDING` order:

```
$array = array(

     array('name' => 'John', 'total' => '33'),
     array('name' => 'Robert', 'total' =>  '66'),
     array('name' => 'John', 'total' => '22')

);

array_multisort($array, SORT_DESC);
var_dump($array);
```

this will output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Robert"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "66"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "33"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "22"
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WhiYRw)