# sort entries from mySQL database in correct order - umlauts are after character "Z"

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, typo3, iso-8859-1

When sorting my values from the mySQL database I get the following wrong sorting order:

`SELECT * FROM tt_news WHERE pid=19 AND deleted=0 AND hidden=0 order by title ASC`

```
A  
B  
C  
...  
Ä  
Ö
```

What can I do against this sorting problem? Ä should be in between or after A and so on.

MySQL server version:  5.0.51a with UTF-8 support

I found out that this has to do with the collation of a database (see german link: http://mysql-faq.sourceforge.net/tables3.html).

The script is embedded into TYPO3 with `setDBinit` set to `SET NAMES utf8` and `forceCharset` set to `UTF-8`. So UTF-8 data should be stored in ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1).

The column has the type `text` and the collation `latin1_swedish_ci`. When I enter `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%'` in phpMyAdmin I get

```
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
```

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%CHARACTER_SET%';` gives me in phpMyAdmin

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

**Attempt No. 1:**

I tried to use `SET NAMES utf8;` in my script but that didn't changed something.

**Attempt No. 2:**

I wanted to do the sorting in PHP (according to this SOQ: [How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)), but that didn't changed the sorting.

```
$title=array();
foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    $title[$key]  = $row['title'];
}
array_multisort($title, SORT_ASC, $result);
```

**Attempt No. 3:**

I used this mySQL statement (taken from http://blog.mixable.de/mysql-order-by-und-deutsche-umlaute/):

```
SELECT * FROM tt_news WHERE pid=19 AND deleted=0 AND hidden=0 order by title COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

No changes in the sorting. Using `utf-8` leads to an error (not allowed collation).

**Attempt No. 4:**

```
SELECT *, REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE(title, 'Ä', 'A'), 'Ö', 'O'), 'Ü', 'U'), 'ä', 'a'), 'ö', 'o'), 'ü','u'), 'ß', 's') AS sortiert FROM tt_news WHERE pid=19 AND deleted=0 AND hidden=0 ORDER BY sortiert
```

Source: http://www.php-faq.de/q-mysql-umlaute-sortieren.html

Works in phpMyAdmin but not in my script. I get the following error: `Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT), (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'replace'`

Can I make the correct sorting in PHP without changing the character set or collation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordering you see is correct *by Swedish rules*: Å, Ä and Ö are the last three letters of the alphabet, after Z. If you don't like it change the column collation so something else.

```
alter table tt_news modify title text collate latin1_general_ci;
```

The `general` variant considers all accented variations of a character distinct, but groups them together when sorting; for example `AZ` comes before `ÄA`. If you require some national standard other than Swedish here's a list of what MySQL supports out of the box: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-we-sets.html

If you can't change the column collation in the database, you can tell MySQL to use a particular collation just for ordering of the query. For example:

```
.... order by title collate latin1_general_ci
```

Comment: How can I determine if it is ASC or DESC order?

Comment: Add ASC or DESC to the end, you can think of "title collate blabla" as a single "unit".

Answer (score 0):

Pure PHP solution:

```
function sortWUmlauts($s1, $s2)
{
    $s1 = $s1['title'];
    $s2 = $s2['title'];
    $search = array('Ä','Ö','Ü','ß');
    $replace = array('A','O','U','s');
    
    return strcasecmp(
       str_ireplace($search, $replace, $s1),
       str_ireplace($search, $replace, $s2)
    );
}

// call
uasort($result, 'sortWUmlauts');
```

Taken from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php#99017

A nice addition would be to have a variable which holds the search key for the associative array (directly embed the function in the uasort call).

Comment: You could use strcoll instead. It orders strings by the rules of the current locale.

Answer (score 0):

use "order by title latin1_german1_ci" for

```
Ä = A
Ö = O
Ü = U
ß = s
```

use "order by title latin1_german2_ci" for

```
Ä = AE
Ö = OE
Ü = UE
ß = ss
```

sorting for more http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-we-sets.html

Comment: This doesn't work, but it almost does - I've given a correct version in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to modify your database to do this (unless you want to, of course). Perhaps you have different columns that you want to sort according to a different language?

Simply specify a different collation in your query, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM tt_news WHERE pid=19 ORDER BY title COLLATE "utf8_german2_ci" ASC
```

Note that if your table is not already in a utf8 collation (maybe it is in a latin1 collation) then you will need to use a latin1 collation for the sorting. In this case you would use `latin1_german2_ci` instead of `utf8_german2_ci` in the query above.

A list of collations along with a useful discussion of their uses is available in the [MySQL reference docs here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html).