# Cakephp sort by first item in array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, sorting

I have an array that looks like the following:

```
Data = array(
'Offer' => array(),
'Country' = array('Name' => Array()) 
)
```

Now if i want to sort on the value of the first item of the `Name` array how would i go around that?

Ive tried this so far:

```
  $dataArray = $originalData['data'];
    $dataArray = Set::sort($dataArray, '{n}.Country.Name', $direction);
```

However this did not work

**Note im using CakePHP `set::Sort` is a part of Cakephp**

Okay seems i wasnt clear enough so here is a more detailed explaination of my problem:

So ive created my own datasource in cake that collects data from an API.

The API returns data in a way that looks like this:

```
data = array(
'Offer' => array('id' => 2, 'name' = 'ExampleName'),
'Stat' => array('Stat1' = 1, 'Stat2' = 2),
'Country => array('Name' => array('name1','name2')
);
```

Now in order to make the user able to sort these data i have to make sure that i display correctly.

This works fine when there is only one value i.e:

```
                $dataArray = $originalData['data'];
            $dataArray = Set::sort($dataArray, '{n}.Stat.Stat1', 'ASC);
            $originalData['data'] = $dataArray;
```

However country is an array so in order to "copy" the code above i need to use the first item of the Country['Name'] array.

to do something like this:

```
 $dataArray = $originalData['data'];
            $dataArray = Set::sort($dataArray, '{n}.Country.Name', $direction);
            $originalData['data'] = $dataArray;
```

However the above code is failing ...

Comment: didn't get your question, do you want something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury Cake has a buildin function to sort i wish to use that

Comment: ahh, what error it is giving? are you getting wrongly sorted data? because it works for me!

Comment: look at this code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6462971, may be you are doing something differently?

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury i actually fixed it your response gave me ideas but not completly please post it as an answer and il accept it ;)

Comment: nice, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

created test data:

```
     $dataArray = array();
     $data = array(
        'Offer' => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'ExampleName'),
        'Stat' => array('Stat1' => 1, 'Stat2' => 2),
        'Country' => array('Name' => array('z','name2'))
     );
      array_push($dataArray,$data);

      $data = array(
        'Offer' => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'ExampleName'),
        'Stat' => array('Stat1' => 1, 'Stat2' => 3),
        'Country' => array('Name' => array('a','name2'))
     );
      array_push($dataArray,$data);

     print_r(Set::sort($dataArray,'{n}.Country.Name','asc'));
```

Link with output array:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6462971