# php nat sort associative array by value without reindex

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
$data['array'] = array(
    1 => array(
        'currency_name' => 'USD',
        'totals' => '310.00 USD'
    ),
    24 => array(
        'currency_name' => 'EUR',
        'totals' => '200.00 EUR'
    ),
    26 => array(
        'currency_name' => 'GBP',
        'totals' => '100.00 GBP'
    )
);
```

I wanted to be sorted by `currency_name` key and I used the following function:

```
// sort the array by currency_name key
$sort = array();
foreach ($data['array'] as $i => $row)
{
    $sort[$i] = $row['currency_name'];
}
array_multisort($sort, SORT_NATURAL, $data['array']);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [currency_name] => EUR
                    [totals] => 200.00 EUR
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [currency_name] => GBP
                    [totals] => 100.00 GBP
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [currency_name] => USD
                    [totals] => 310.00 USD
                )

        )

)
```

**Expected:**

```
Array
(
    [array] => Array
        (
            [24] => Array
                (
                    [currency_name] => EUR
                    [totals] => 200.00 EUR
                )

            [26] => Array
                (
                    [currency_name] => GBP
                    [totals] => 100.00 GBP
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [currency_name] => USD
                    [totals] => 310.00 USD
                )

        )

)
```

This is reindexing the array, which I don't want. I need those keys later on.

**Note:**
* The method I've used above was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)
* I need `SORT_NATURAL` as I use this function for other strings too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can read from `array_multisort` documentation, only associative (string) keys are preserved. You can use `uasort` instead.

```
uasort($data['array'], function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['currency_name'], $b['currency_name']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try  **natcasesort($array)**  function. This function sort an array using a case insensitive "natural order" algorithm.It returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.