# SORT BY in MySQL query does not change the order in the query results array

Tags: php, mysql

This MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM notes WHERE school_code = 'brisch' ORDER BY ID DESC
```

works in the MySQL terminal (showing records in descending ID order where they held in the table in ascending order) but when I use it in a PHP script as:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE school_code = '$skcode' ORDER BY ID DESC";
$nresult = mysql_query($query);
$nnum = mysql_numrows($nresult);
```

And then output the rows using:

```
$i=0;
while ($i < $nnum) 
{
   // take each row from the array $nresult
   $i++;
}
```

It displays the rows in the table order i.e. by ascending ID  I thought if they pulled from the table in descending order they would be stored in the array in that same order.

Am I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: I think we'd need to see the bit inside the curly brackets.

Comment: Also, note that you're using a deprecated api

Comment: Strawberry, thanks for the heads up on the deprecation.  Inside the brackets is just something like: $nnotes = mysql_result($nresult,$i,'notes');
   $time = mysql_result($nresult,$i,'created');
   $usern2 = mysql_result($nresult,$i,'op_code');
   $nid = mysql_result($nresult,$i,'id');                                              etc....  and these fields then get put in their own table and this is repeated for each value of i. will try edvinas.me's solution shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is most likely how you iterate through the results. Replace while loop with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and it should work:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($nresult)) {

    echo $row['id'];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Nah, that didn't work either - thanks for the suggestion though.  I also tried counting from $nnum to 0 in the WHILE loop - didn't work either! But tried something else I found - answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Did this:

```
$key = "ID";
array_multisort($nresult, SORT_DESC, $key);
```

got it from:

[How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)

Comment: I should add that I still need the 'ORDER BY $key DESC' part in the mysql query.  (Though I'm using the deprecated MYSQL api, still - so prob going to be different for MySQLi.)