# How to sort the following associative array in php

Tags: php

I have following associative array:

```
$weight["fan"]=10;
$weight["clock"]=2;
$weight["wheel"]=12;
$weight["Bicycle"]=20;
```

How should I sort the above array ascending or descending w.r.t value as follows:

```
$weight["Bicycle"]=20;
$weight["wheel"]=12;
$weight["fan"]=10;
$weight["clock"]=2;
```

Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+sort+array+by+values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`arsort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) you can sort like you want to.

```
arsort($weight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use -

```
arsort($weight);
```

This sort the array in reverse order, and keep the keys intact.