# PHP sort an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this. I need to sort countries (array key) by [0][amount] value.

```
Array
(
    [Germany] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 50
                    [count] => 1
                )

        )

    [Poland] => Array
        (

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => 80
                    [count] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

Result should be Poland first and Germany. Any idea in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)

Comment: uasort  and then array_keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it..

```
$amount = array();
foreach ($originArray as $key => $value)
{
        $amount[$key] = $value[0]['amount'];
}
array_multisort($amount, SORT_DESC, $originArray);
```