# how to properly sort the array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
$arr = array('Stone', 'Gem', 'Star', ..., 'Star', 'Rock', 'Salt', ..., 'Metal', 'Cotton', 'Gem',...);
$array = array_count_values($arr);
```

So the output is like this:

```
Array
(
    [Stone] => 234
    [Gem] => 231
    [Star] => 123
    [Rock] => 232
)
```

Now I am trying to sort it alphabetically like,

```
[Gem] => ...
[Star] => ...
[Stone] => ...
[Rock] => ...
```

I tried this one:

```
sort($arr);
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' : '.$value;
}
```

But the output is not what I have expected it look like this:

```
0 : 11 : 12 : 13 : 14 : 15 : 16 : 17 : 18 : 19 : 110 : 11 ...
```

Any ideas how I can correctly sort this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `ksort()` ?

```
ksort($arr)

print($arr)
```

You can get the doc over [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting by keys, not values, so you should use [ksort()](http://php.net/ksort) function.