# php, how to sort three arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have three arrays. How do I sort them by key order

```
    Array
(
    [network-id] => 4
    [network-subdomain] => n3
    [source-id] => 89
    [about-page-id] => 5613
    [contacts-page-id] => 2605
    [logo-provider] => option-tree
    [alias] => Template 3
    [template-subdomain] => template3
    [order] => 3
)
Array
(
    [network-id] => 2
    [network-subdomain] => n1
    [source-id] => 87
    [about-page-id] => 2
    [contacts-page-id] => 2754
    [logo-provider] => redux
    [alias] => Template 1
    [template-subdomain] => template1
    [order] => 1
)
Array
(
    [network-id] => 3
    [network-subdomain] => n2
    [source-id] => 88
    [about-page-id] => 2
    [contacts-page-id] => 26
    [logo-provider] => option-tree
    [alias] => Template 2
    [template-subdomain] => template2
    [order] => 2
)
```

Comment: *How to sort them* -  what do you mean?

Comment: Have you tried usort?

Comment: 3 different array ?????

Comment: These 3 arrays i get in loop foreah

Comment: foreach ($themes as $value) {
            $meta = $this->themesMeta->getThemeMeta($value);

            $caption = $value;

                if($meta) {
                    $caption = $meta['alias'].' (<a href="https://'. $meta['template-subdomain']. '.' .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'" target="_blank">Preview</a>)';
                }


            $options .= sprintf($optionTemplate, $value, $caption);
        }

Comment: Try reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Comment: @ВячеславРешетняков Hello! Can you please add your comment code in to yur question, by clicking on **edit** on the question and then copy/pasting your comments, as comment code is harder to read and understand. It would also be useful if you can also show what shape of result you want from the question, cheers

Comment: Do you want the key sort for each array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by using usort

```
function compare_order($a, $b)
{
    return strnatcmp($a['order'], $b['order']);
}

// sort alphabetically by order
 usort($a, 'compare_order');
```

you can see [demo](https://eval.in/573031)