# How to get array key in alphabetical order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is my code. I want to get   **location_name** in alphabetical order and **location_id** and **id** want to relevant each **location_name**

in modal

```
function get_exam_locations_for_view() {
  $d = $this->db->get('exm_exam_location');
  if ($d) {
    return $d;
  }
}
```

in view

```
foreach ($ex_locations->result_array() as $row) {
  $loc_name = $row['location_name'];
  $loc_id = $row['location_id'];
  $loc_ai = $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to sort array based on key.

```
$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");

ksort($fruits);
```

and You can also sort the results in query itself.

```
function get_exam_locations_for_view() {
    $d = $this->db->select('exm_exam_location')->orderBy('exm_exam_location', 'asc')->get();

    if ($d) {
        return $d;
    }
}
```