# PHP array value replacement (or alternative)

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I’m working on a system that fetches info from an external source and then processes the data a bit. I’ve gotten it to do my wished functionality for the client when processing the data in JavaScript. What’s next is that I want to store the info in a database. But here I want to process it solely in PHP (or in some other server side way of doing it). What’s currently confusing me is some array replacement stuff.

What I have now stored in an array is players ID, Times, Name and Bikes. The data I'm fetching is dividing the bikes into 2 classes (2 and 4stroke) so I have to fetch each set of data individually. The array "rec450" contains the relevant information from the 4stroke class. What I want to do here is compare the 2stroke class for a given user and see if the time is faster on the 2stroke. If it is, I want to replace the data in the "rec450" array with the new info from the 2stroke array. So I would like to have this functionality:

```
if(class1[‘time’] < class2[‘time’]){   
  replace class1 info with the class2 info;    
}
```

Here is the PHP code I’m currently using:

```
//Pushing the data I want from the fetched array to a new array. This array is no longer associative.
foreach ($rr450f as $key => $value) {
    $tmpArr = array(
        "name" => $value['name'],
        "time" => $value['time'],
        "bike" => $value['bike'],
        "uid" => $value['uid']
    );
    array_push($rec450, $tmpArr);
}
```

This is how I try to change the values for the rec450 array:

```
foreach($rr250 as $key => $value){

    foreach ($rec450 as $k => $v) {
        if($value['uid'] == $v['uid']){

            $k['time'] = $value['time'];
            $k['bike'] = $value['bike'];
            $k['name'] = $value['name'];
            $k['uid'] = $value['uid'];

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the print_r of the rec450 array (structure) I’m using:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Player One
        [time] => 17068
        [bike] => rmz450(2013)
        [uid] => 90970
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Player Two
        [time] => 8959
        [bike] => 450sxf(2016)
        [uid] => 76800
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Player Three
        [time] => 8300
        [bike] => yz450f(2016)
        [uid] => 90380
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Player Four
        [time] => 8791
        [bike] => 450sxf(2016)
        [uid] => 89240
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Player Five
        [time] => 19640
        [bike] => 450sxf(2016)
        [uid] => 98809
    )
)
```

This is the array that contains the 2stroke data in it's base form, before any columns are filtered out.

```
Array
(
    [90970] => Array
        (
        [time] => 11929
        [bike] => rm250(2008)
        [number] => 123
        [name] => Player One
        [uid] => 90970
        [url] => /path/to/player/info
    )

[9248] => Array
    (
        [time] => 9922
        [bike] => cr250(2007)
        [number] => 124
        [name] => Player Twelve
        [uid] => 60030
        [url] => /path/to/player/info
    )
)
```

At this stage what I want is some way to replace the 4stroke times with the 2stroke times if a Player was faster on the 2stroke. If it's unnecessary to do the filtering out of unnecessary data and losing the association of the array when I am doing the rr450f to rec450, I could skip that.

Would really appreciate any info of how I can replace the values in the 1st array with the ones from the 2nd one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking at this wrong.

Essentially what you are trying to achieve is to sort a multidimensional array by the key of 'time'.

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Try the following code after you created your array

```
$list = array();
foreach ($rec450 as $key => $row)
  {
    $list[$key] = $row['time'];
  }
array_multisort($list, SORT_ASC, $rec450);
```

What's happening here is that we're creating an array out of all the times and then sorting the main array according to that new array.

I must add some credit behind this, from this original post, and accepted answer.

[How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)