# Re-sorting array into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php

In my user_table, I have "UID", and "Gameid".
And of course, when I run the query I get something like:

```
array() {
 [0] => array() {
  UID    => 1,
  gameid => 334613
 },
 [1] => array() {
  UID    => 2,
  gameid => 704234
 },
 [2] => array() {
  UID => 3,
  gameid => 704234
 }
}
```

The UID is auto incremented, and the gameid is based off what the user is playing currently based off steam and the value is always going to be random. So I want to take the above arrays and place them into a new array sorted by gameid.

I hope that makes sense, let me know if I need to clarify, thank you in advanced.

Sorry for not explaining right,

I'm trying to get the above array into this:

```
$array = array (
    (334613) => array (
        [0] => 1
    ),
    (704234) => array (
        [0] => 2,
        [1] => 3
    )
);
```

Thank you again!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)

Comment: When youu "run the query" then there's also the option to have the database sort results right away.

Comment: In short https://3v4l.org/RZq10 `array_multisort(array_column($array, 'gameid'), SORT_DESC, $array);` Use `$newArray = clone $array;` if you don't want to pass-by-reference