# Sort array elements based on their return value from a custom function call

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, custom-function

Is there a way to sort a PHP array by return value of a custom function? Like Python's `sorted(arr, key=keyfn)` or Clojure's `(sort-by keyfn arr)`,

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    $key_a = keyfn($a);
    $key_b = keyfn($b);
    if ($key_a == $key_b) return 0;
    if ($key_a < $key_b) return -1;
    return 1;
});
```

The above does what I want, but it's verbose and it calls `keyfn` (which can be slow) much more often than needed.  Is there a more performant approach?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ksort.php ?

Comment: @Zyigh it sorts by _key_ as in the key of an associative array, I am looking for a way to sort by key _function_

Comment: I suppose python's function calls predicate too, on each compare step.

Comment: Why wouldn't your key be the result of the function ?

Comment: @u_mulder https://pasteboard.co/HvNO1Yb.png 1 call per list element

Comment: @Zyigh So do you suggest turning the array into an associative one and then sorting it by key? What if several elements have the same value of `keyfn`?

Comment: All array are associative in PHP. I don't get why you need this and how it would return the same result...

Comment: Nice, but in php you have to create a cache with results manually(

Comment: [uksort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uksort.php) allow you to sort by key with a home made function might be more appropriate maybe

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up implementing it this way:

```
function sort_by($key_f, $arr) {
    $values = array_map($key_f, $arr);
    asort($values);
    $sorted_arr = array();

    foreach ($values as $idx => $value) {
        $sorted_arr[] = $arr[$idx];
    }

    return $sorted_arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some simple code for caching results of `predicate` and sorting (using `spaceship` operator which reduces lines where you return 0,1,-1). In case of `predicate` result as `int` you can even return `$key_a - $key_b`:

```
$array = [2,2,2,1,1,0,0,8];
$values_cache = [];
usort($array, function ($a, $b) use (&$values_cache) {
    $key_a = isset($values_cache[$a]) ? $values_cache[$a] : ($values_cache[$a] = keyfn($a));
    $key_b = isset($values_cache[$b]) ? $values_cache[$b] : ($values_cache[$b] = keyfn($b));
    return $key_a <=> $key_b;
});
echo '<pre>', print_r($array), '</pre>';

function keyfn($v) {
    echo 'call a keyfn' . PHP_EOL;
    return 2 * $v;
}
```

Simple fiddle https://3v4l.org/W1N7Y

Answer (score 0):

From PHP7.4 and higher you can modernize/refine @u_mulder's snippet using the null coalescing assignment operator as the following.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/olhnd))

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    static $cache;
    return ($cache[$a] ??= keyfn($a)) <=> ($cache[$b] ??= keyfn($b));
});
```

---

Alternatively, making mapped calls of your custom function will be more concise, but will result in a greater number of custom function calls. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dMtPA))

```
array_multisort(array_map('keyfn', $array), $array);
```

This can be prevented in a classic loop, again with the null coalescing operator, but it may be a little harder to conceptualize with the double-assignment line. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WSHNl))

```
$new = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
    $new[] = $cache[$v] ??= keyfn($v);
}
array_multisort($new, $array);
```