# Grouping data from array by field - in an even arrangement

Tags: php

I have tables with data, I would like to sort it equally according to the **type** field in order to get such a result:

```
1 - http://site1.com
2 - http://sitex.com
3 - http://sites.com
4 - http://site2.com
5 - http://site1.com
1 - http://site2.com
2 - http://site3.com
3 - http://site6.com
4 - http://site1.com
5 - http://siteX.com
1 - http://site2.com
2 - http://site8.com
3 - http://site9.com
4 - http://site1.com
5 - http://site1.com
```

I want to group the mixed data from the array into equal groups according to the value of the type field, from 1-5. I will add that the array does not always have an equal amount of data for *type=X*. Sometimes there are more and sometimes less

php script:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
   array('type' => 1,'url' => 'http://site1.com'),
   array('type' => 4,'url' => 'http://site2.com'),
   array('type' => 1,'url' => 'http://site2.com'),
   array('type' => 2,'url' => 'http://sitex.com'),
   array('type' => 5,'url' => 'http://site1.com'),
   array('type' => 1,'url' => 'http://site2.com'),
   array('type' => 2,'url' => 'http://site3.com'),
   array('type' => 3,'url' => 'http://sites.com'),
   array('type' => 4,'url' => 'http://site1.com'),
   array('type' => 5,'url' => 'http://siteX.com'),
   array('type' => 3,'url' => 'http://site6.com'),
   array('type' => 4,'url' => 'http://site1.com'),
   array('type' => 5,'url' => 'http://site1.com'),
   array('type' => 2,'url' => 'http://site8.com'),
   array('type' => 3,'url' => 'http://site9.com'),
);

foreach ($arr as $a){
    echo $a['type'].' - '.$a['url'].'<br>';
}

/*-- result

1 - http://site1.com
4 - http://site2.com
1 - http://site2.com
2 - http://sitex.com
5 - http://site1.com
1 - http://site2.com
2 - http://site3.com
3 - http://sites.com
4 - http://site1.com
5 - http://siteX.com
3 - http://site6.com
4 - http://site1.com
5 - http://site1.com
2 - http://site8.com
3 - http://site9.com

--*/
?>
```

Do you have any idea how I can get such a result?

Comment: So u want data based on type orde sorting ? like 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ?

Comment: Yes. 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Comment: I checked, unfortunately I did not find any solutions that worked in my case. I want to sort the array into equal portions of data (1,2,3,4,5...1,2,3,4,5), not all array (1,1,2,2,3,3...)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$mapped = [];

foreach ($arr as $a){
    $mapped[$a['type']][] = $a['url'];
}
```

Comment: What eror message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code may work for you..

```html
<?php function group_by($key, $data) {
    $result = array();

    foreach($data as $val) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $val)){
    $result[$val[$key]][] = $val;
    }else{
    $result[""][] = $val;
    }
    }
    
    return $result;
}

$arr = array(
   array('type' => 1,'url' => 'http://site1.com'),
   array('type' => 4,'url' => 'http://site2.com'),
   array('type' => 1,'url' => 'http://site2.com'),
   array('type' => 2,'url' => 'http://sitex.com'),
   array('type' => 5,'url' => 'http://site1.com'),
   array('type' => 1,'url' => 'http://site2.com'),
   array('type' => 2,'url' => 'http://site3.com'),
   array('type' => 3,'url' => 'http://sites.com'),
   array('type' => 4,'url' => 'http://site1.com'),
   array('type' => 5,'url' => 'http://siteX.com'),
   array('type' => 3,'url' => 'http://site6.com'),
   array('type' => 4,'url' => 'http://site1.com'),
   array('type' => 5,'url' => 'http://site1.com'),
   array('type' => 2,'url' => 'http://site8.com'),
   array('type' => 3,'url' => 'http://site9.com'),
);

$byGroup = group_by("type", $arr);

echo "<pre>" . var_export($byGroup, true) . "</pre>";
?>
```