# Sort and associaative array by specific value

Tags: php, arrays, associative

If this has been answered before I apologize (I haven't seen to found it). I have a game pool website that wishes to sort by points (pts). In the below example I want 'Team B' to be first as their points are higher then Team A's at *22* compared to *12*. While the solution on this page ([How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)) seemed to be very similar to what I was looking for I wasn't able to get it to work.

```
Array
(

[0] => Team Object
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => Team A
        [games_played] => 13
        [wins] => 6
        [losses] => 7
        [ot_losses] => 0
        [pts] => 12
        [goals_for] => 7.5
        [goals_against] => 22
        [streak] => 6-7
    )

[1] => Team Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Team B
        [games_played] => 13
        [wins] => 11
        [losses] => 2
        [ot_losses] => 0
        [pts] => 22
        [goals_for] => 51
        [goals_against] => 19
        [streak] => 11-2
    )
```

I suspect I'm on the right path with the following but missing something...

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array_objects as $key => $row)
{
    $new_array[$key] = $row['pts'];
}
array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $array_objects);
```

Comment: `$price` should be `$new_array`.

Comment: Looks like you copied the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php but forgot to rename the variable everywhere.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the `usort` answer there anyway. And if this data comes from your db, adding an ORDER BY to your query will be better than sorting it in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)