# Rank keys of an associative array according to their values (error in function)

Tags: php, associative-array

I want to rank the `keys` of an associative array in [php](/questions/tagged/php) based upon their values. (top to down as 1, 2, 3....). Keys having same value will have same rank.

> Here function `getRanks()` is meant to return an array containing `keys` and the `ranks` (number).
>
> I expect it to return like this (this is sorted value wise in descending)
>
> ```
> Array
>         (
>             [b] => 1
>             [a] => 2
>             [d] => 3
>             [c] => 3
>             [e] => 4
>         )
> ```

***There is issue in assigning the `ranks` (values) in the `$ranks array` which is to be returned.***

What am I doing wrong? Do these loops even do something?

**Code:**

```
$test = array('a'=> 50, 'b'=>60, 'c'=>20, 'd'=>20, 'e'=>10);
$json = json_encode($test);

print_r(getRanks($json)); 

function getRanks($json) {
    $tmp_arr = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $ranks = array();

    uasort($tmp_arr, function($a, $b){
        return $a == $b ? 0 : $a > $b ? -1 : 1; //descending
    });

    $keys = array_keys($tmp_arr); //after sorting
    $ranks = array_fill_keys($keys, 0); //copy keys
    $ranks[$keys[0]] = 1; //first val => rank 1

//------- WORKS FINE UNTIL HERE ------------------



    // need to fix the ranks assignment
    for($i=1; $i<count($keys)-1; $i++) {
        for($j=$i; $j < count($keys)-1; $j++) {
            if($tmp_arr[$keys[$j]] == $tmp_arr[$keys[$j+1]]) {
                $rank[$keys[$j]] = $i;
            }
        }
     }

    return $ranks;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I've already sorted by value. I need to fill ranks according to these sorted values in `$ranks` array. The suggested duplicate is not my question.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems unnecessarily complicated. In my version I kept the json-related copying part of it but finished it off in a simpler way:

```
function getRanks($json) {
    $tmp_arr = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    asort($tmp_arr);. // sort ascending
    $i=0; $lv=null;$ranks = array();
   foreach ($tmp_arr as $k=>$v) {
     if ($v>$lv){ $i++; $lv=$v;}
     $ranks[$k]=$i;
   }
   return $ranks;
}
```

See the demo here: https://rextester.com/LTOA23372

In a slightly modified version you you can also do the **ranking in a descending order**, see here: https://rextester.com/HESQP10053

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried with another approach.
I think it *may not be the good solution* because of *high memory & CPU time* consumption.

For small arrays (in my case) it works fine.

***(I've posted because it may be an answer)***

> It creates array of unique values and fetches `ranks` accordingly.

```
$test = array('a'=> 50, 'b'=>60, 'c'=>20, 'd'=>20, 'e'=>10);
$json = json_encode($test);

print_r(getRanks($json));

function getRanks($json) {
    $tmp_arr = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    arsort($tmp_arr);
    $uniq_vals = array_values(array_unique($tmp_arr)); // unique values indexed numerically from 0

    foreach ($tmp_arr as $k => $v) {
        $tmp_arr[$k] = array_search($v, $uniq_vals) + 1; //as rank will start with 1
    }
    return $tmp_arr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the simple thing that  you can do it by using php array function check example given below.

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");
asort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: That's not what I requested for. I have already sorted the array.

Comment: Can you please post your initial array and result array you need ?

Comment: I've provided in question with expected result. your answer sorts the array, that's not what I needed.