# Sort array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I write my project in Laravel 5.8.
I write code which generate array.

I have this array (result by dd($array)):

```
array:15 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "xkey" => 118
    "key" => 0
    "date" => "2020-01-19"
    "id" => 118
    "dishType" => "3"
    "name" => "Mięso z piersi kurczaka, bez skóry"
    "summaryQuantity" => "100"
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "xkey" => 251
    "key" => 0
    "date" => "2020-01-19"
    "id" => 251
    "dishType" => "3"
    "name" => "Olej rzepakowy"
    "summaryQuantity" => "23"
  ]
]
```

I need sort my result by "name" ASC.

i try:

```
ksort($fruits);
```

But it's not working.
How can I make it?

This code help me:

```
array_multisort(array_column($shoppingArrayTmpData, 'name'), SORT_ASC, $shoppingArrayTmpData);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow : Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Comment: Hi:) This help me: array_multisort(array_column($shoppingArrayTmpData, 'name'), SORT_ASC, $shoppingArrayTmpData);

Comment: Hello @opolopo, if you resolve it you can close it. Try to don't keep open questions were resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy for collection [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby);

The **collect** method convert array to collection

The **sortBy** method sorts the collection by the given key.

And the **all** method will change collection to array(PS: you can use `toarray()`)

```php
collect($array)->sortBy('name')->all();
```

Comment: @opolopo I change to asc

Comment: Now it will work,  you need to generate a collection and then you can sort with collections functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
collect($array)->sortBy('name')->all();
```

Comment: "_Try this one_" does a poor job of educating/empowering the OP and future researchers as to how the syntax works and why it is good advice.  Please be more generous with your knowledge.