# Sort multidimensional Array in PHP ascending

Tags: php, html

I have an array which is inserted into an HTML Table

[image]

The problem is I want to sort it according to the value of counter. I tried an example which looks like this but it won't work.

```
foreach($analysis_data as $nr => $inhalt){
    $country[$nr] = strtolower($inhalt['country']);
    $counter[$nr] = strtolower($inhalt['counter']);
}

array_multisort($counter, SORT_ASC, $analysis_data);,
```

Does anybody know how to sort this multi dimensional array?

Comment: `SORCT_ASC`? Maybe `SORT`?

Comment: Yes there was a typing mistake but didn't changed the result

Comment: @fhprogrammer there was a similar problem posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php
maybe it can help you

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir: Yes just saw it that this problem was similar. Was able to fix it with help of this

Answer (score 0):

Due to the documentation third parameter of `array_multisort` function is `array1_sort_flags`. But you pass array with data.

I assume this is the right way to use it in your case.

```
array_multisort($counter, SORT_ASC);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$analysis_data  = array(
    array('counter'=>34,'country'=>'Germany'),
    array('counter'=>2,'country'=>'Vorarlberg'),
    array('counter'=>9,'country'=>'Oberoesterreich'),
    array('counter'=>5,'country'=>'Wien'),
    array('counter'=>3,'country'=>'Switzerland'),
    array('counter'=>6,'country'=>'Salzburg'),
    array('counter'=>1,'country'=>'Niederoesterreich'),
    array('counter'=>3,'country'=>'Czech Republic'),
    array('counter'=>1,'country'=>'Steiermark'),
);

foreach($analysis_data as $nr => $inhalt){
    $country[$nr] = strtolower($inhalt['country']);
    $counter[$nr] = strtolower($inhalt['counter']);
}

array_multisort($counter, SORT_ASC, $analysis_data);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I want it ascending not descending. Keeping that out of mind, it doesn't work like this either