# PHP - Sort an array of arrays by the arrays key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

The closest answer I saw was [This One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php), but that's not what I need. 
Let's say I have the following array:

```
$array = array (
    'docker-compose' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '...',
    ),
    'darwin' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '...',
    ),
    'linux' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '....',
    ),
    'windows' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '...',
    ),
    'debian' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '...',
      'install_command' => '....',
    ),
    'rpm' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '...',
      'install_command' => '...',
    ),
    'helm' => 
    array (
      'install_command' => '...',
      'wiki_url' => '',
    ),
    'docker' => 
    array (
      'install_command' => '....',
    ),
  )
```

And I want to sort it according to a simple logic that comes out from the following array:

```
$artifacts_importance_order = array(
    'helm',
    'rpm',
    'debian',
    'docker',
    'docker-compose',
    'linux',
    'windows',
    'darwin',
  );
```

If I was able to get the array's `key` inside `usort()` I'd do something like that:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($artifacts_importance_order){
  return (array_search(get_array_key($a),$artifacts_importance_order) < array_search(get_array_key($b),$artifacts_importance_order));  
});
```

Of course, `get_array_key` does not exist, but I'd like to know if there's something else I can do to get the key. 
The desired result will be:

```
  $array = array (
    'helm' => 
    array (
      'install_command' => '...',
      'wiki_url' => '',
    ),
    'rpm' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '...',
      'install_command' => '...',
    ),
    'debian' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '...',
      'install_command' => '....',
    ),
    'docker' => 
    array (
      'install_command' => '....',
    ),
    'docker-compose' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '...',
    ),
    'linux' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '....',
    ),
    'windows' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '...',
    ),
    'darwin' => 
    array (
      'download_url' => '...',
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use [`uksort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) instead as this passes the key values to the sort...

```
uksort($array, function($a, $b) use ($artifacts_importance_order){
    return (array_search($a,$artifacts_importance_order) > array_search($b,$artifacts_importance_order));
});
```

Comment: Exactly the function I was looking for. Thanks for that. Working as expected. Didn't try Jaquarth's answer, might work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

A more simple approach. You can [`array_flip`](https://3v4l.org/YDApb) your order so they become the keys, then [`array_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) these keys to change the order.

See it working over a [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/YDApb)

```
$orderedArray = array_replace(array_flip($artifacts_importance_order), $array);
```