# Order arrays inside arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am quite new at php, I am trying to order arrays inside a quite nested array according to a property inside the  arrays that need sorting.

```
<?php 

  $unOrderedArray = array(
    'fields' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'field_60f6e595c18cc',
         'name' => 'Should be last',
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'field_60f6bcf3e0b87',
        'name' => 'Should be second',
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'field_60f6adb77c6f3',
        'name' => 'Should be first',
      )
    )
  );    

?>
```

So the `key` property has a value that could be ordered alphabetically.

Is this posibble?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Sort a Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-a-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: It does not print the results I am trying to do `var_dump(usort($unOrderedArray, 'sortByOrder'));` but I just get `bool(true)`

Comment: The link I provided shows a different solution. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use `usort`, where you can specify a custom sorting function. The solution would be:

```php
  usort($unOrderedArray['fields'], function($a, $b) {
     return  $a['key'] > $b['key'] ? 1 : -1;
  });
```

Obs.: I return integers in the function to avoid warnings.

The `usort` function only returns a `bool` informing whether succeded or not. The array is passed via reference and its value is changed while sorting. Thus, to observe the results one has to print the original array.

```php
  print_r($unOrderedArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I see the ordered array, I am trying to print this but just get `1`

Comment: You have to print the array, it is passed via reference: `print_r($unOrderedArray);`. The function only returns whether succeded or not.

Comment: Thanks I did `var_dump($unOrderedArray['fields']);` and it worked.