# How to sort an array within an associative array with its value using php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I have an array like:

```
$a = array(array("fghfg12" => 34),
           array("dfgdf23" => 97),
           array("wetw13" => 65),
           array("rtyr567" => 18));
```

I want to sort this array by its value.
That means I want the result like:

```
$a = array(array("rtyr567" => 18),
           array("fghfg12" => 34),
           array("wetw13" => 65),
           array("dfgdf23" => 97));
```

For this I am using:

```
uksort($a , function($key1, $key2) use ($res) {
      return (array_search($key1, $res) > array_search($key2, $res));
  });
```

Another method:

```
$arr2ordered = array() ;
foreach (array_keys($a) as $key) {
   $arr2ordered[$key] = $a[$key] ;
}
```

But I didn't get my result;

I already tried with this also:

```
$price = array();
    foreach ($a as $key => $row)
    {
        $price[$key] = $row;
    }
    array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $a);
    print_r($a);
```

But still, I didnt get my result

Comment: look at there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php

Comment: I already tried with that. But I didn't get my result.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know what the key of each inner array will be, you can map `current()` over `$a` to get the first value in each inner array, then use that array of values as the first argument to `array_multisort()` to sort `$a`.

```
array_multisort(array_map('current', $a), $a);
```

Check it out: https://3v4l.org/4Zu0q

Answer (score 0):

try that code

```
$a = array(array("fghfg12" => 34),
       array("dfgdf23" => 97),
       array("wetw13" => 65),
       array("rtyr567" => 18));

usort($a, function($a, $b){
return array_values($a) > array_values($b);
});
```

But only for your structure..