# Php needed to order divs depending on percentage obtained

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form that people fill out and a results page which displays results as follows;
[image]

I'd like to order these divs from top to bottom based on the percentage found while also retaining the colour border wanted for that category. I know some php but not entirely sure how i'd tackle this ordering, any advice would be great.

I have an idea on how to order the divs by putting the results into an array and ordering it, but i'm not sure on how id print the display with the correct border.

Below is the php I have an the display of my divs;

```
@php
                    $varA = App\Http\Controllers\ViewTeacherResults::teacherResultsInt();
                    $varB = App\Http\Controllers\ViewTeacherResults::teacherResultsCre();
                    $varC = App\Http\Controllers\ViewTeacherResults::teacherResultsSoc();
                    $varD = App\Http\Controllers\ViewTeacherResults::teacherResultsPer();
                    $varE = App\Http\Controllers\ViewTeacherResults::teacherResultsMuc();
                    $varF = App\Http\Controllers\ViewTeacherResults::teacherResultsMoc();
                    $varG = App\Http\Controllers\ViewTeacherResults::teacherResultsSp();
@endphp

<div class="table-container">
      <div class="table-item intellect-border">Intellectual: {{round($varA)}}%</div>
      <div class="table-item create-border">Creative: {{round($varB)}}%</div>
      <div class="table-item social-border">Social: {{round($varC)}}%</div>
      <div class="table-item percept-border">Perceptual: {{round($varD)}}%</div>
      <div class="table-item musc-border">Muscular: {{round($varE)}}%</div>
      <div class="table-item motor-border">Motor: {{round($varF)}}%</div>
      <div class="table-item spir-border">Spiritual: {{round($varG)}}%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? PHP won't magically sort these tags. Also, how is tihs related to CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store it as an array like this

```
$array = [
    [
        'name' => 'Intellectual',
        'border' => 'intellect-border',
        'val' => $varA, 
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Creative',
        'border' => 'create-border',
        'val' => $varB,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Social',
        'border' => 'social-border',
        'val' => $varC,
    ]
];
```

Because your question is relevant, then you can use usort for sorting, check here [How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19454643/7590238)

```
usort($array, function ($item1, $item2) {
   return $item1['val'] <=> $item2['val'];
});
```

and last you need to draw looping for each div like this

```
<div class="table-container">
    <?php foreach($array as $i):?>
        <div class="table-item <?= $i['border']; ?>"><?= $i['name']; ?>: <?= round($i['val']); ?>%</div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

this live demo [output](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xgan93dz)
[image]

Note : check this line for ascending sort

```
$item1['val'] <=> $item2['val'];
```

and you can swap to this if you want descending sort

```
$item2['val'] <=> $item1['val'];
```