# PHP: Sorting a specefic key of an associative multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, associative-array

i want my foreach loop test specefic  $key of "age"from my associative decoded json data  for example and ascending or descendig sort whole array by value of "age" can anyone help me?

```json
[
  {
    "number": 1,
    "name": "masoud ahmadi",
    "age": 16,
    "school": "Amir kabir"
  },
  {
    "number": 2,
    "name": "mohammad hosseini",
    "age": 14,
    "school": "Andishe"
  },
  {
    "number": 3,
    "name": "Mohammad hosseini",
    "age": 14,
    "school": "Allame"
  },
  {
    "number": 4,
    "name": "ali akabr",
    "age": 16,
    "school": "Allame"
  }
]
```

Comment: Convert your JSON to an array using `json_decode($jsonString, true)` then see  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1597736/296555.

Comment: Why was this question upvoted?  It is a super-duplicate requirements-dump question and showed absolutely no research or effort?  ...this is actually part of the hardcoded definition for why a question should be downvoted.  Mouseover the up/downvote buttons to understand how to vote.