# sort xml div by child node PHP SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

so I have a list of `<div>`'s in an xml file. I'm parsing the file using php's simpleXML

I can generate an array of all the divs with the following:

```
$divArray = $xmldoc->text->body->children();
```

But now I would like to order the $divArray by different childNodes (author, title, date) within the div.

The div looks like this.

```
<div>
    <bibl>
       <author>
       <title>
       <date>
   </bibl>
</div>
```

So how can I take $divArray and sort it by `<author>` or `<title>` or `<date>`?

Thanks for your help.
jw

Comment: Use `usort` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076506/using-usort-with-simplexml

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP sorting issue with simpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023029/php-sorting-issue-with-simplexml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic procedure is

1. cast a `SimpleXMLElement` into an array
2. write a comparison function that accepts two `SimpleXMLElement` arguments
3. sort the array with the comparison function using `usort()`

I can only guess at your original XML structure, but I think it looks something like this:

```
$xml = <<<EOT
<root>
<text>
    <body>
        <div>
            <bibl>
                <author>A</author>
                <title>A</title>
                <date>1</date>
            </bibl>
        </div>
        <div>
            <bibl>
                <author>B</author>
                <title>B</title>
                <date>2</date>
            </bibl>
        </div>
        <div>
            <bibl>
                <author>D</author>
                <title>D</title>
                <date>4</date>
            </bibl>
        </div>
        <div>
            <bibl>
                <author>C</author>
                <title>C</title>
                <date>3</date>
            </bibl>
        </div>
    </body>
</text>
</root>
EOT;

$xmldoc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

Step 1: Cast to array. Note that *your* `$divArray` *is not actually an array*!

```
$divSXE = $xmldoc->text->body->children(); // is a SimpleXMLElement, not an array!
// print_r($divSXE);
$divArray = array();
foreach($divSXE->div as $d) {
    $divArray[] = $d;
}
// print_r($divArray);
```

Step 2: write a comparison function. Since the array is a list of `SimpleXMLElement`s, the comparison function must accept `SimpleXMLElement` arguments. `SimpleXMLElement`s need explicit casting to get string or integer values.

```
function author_cmp($a, $b) {
    $va = (string) $a->bibl->author;
    $vb = (string) $b->bibl->author;
    if ($va===$vb) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($va<$vb) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Step 3: Sort the array with `usort()`

```
usort($divArray, 'author_cmp');
print_r($divArray);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Your response is very detailed and helpful. Likewise your clarification about SimpleXML object versus Array is very helpful for an amateur like me. :) It works great. If you have time, do you think you could try to briefly explain how the cmp functions works. I've been reading the manual, but it seems really confusing to me. No problem if you don't have time.

Comment: Custom comparison functions for sorting are a pretty common feature of many languages. See [the usort() page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for a description and example. The basic idea is to have a function which takes two of the things you're sorting and returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on whether the first thing is less than, equal to, or greater than the second thing. usort (or whatever) will then invoke this function you supplied whenever it needs to compare two things.

Comment: Thanks very much -- that's a very helpful explanation.