# Order XML data output by date

Tags: php, xml

I do have following XML-data:

```
 <schedule>
  <event>
    <date>2017-08-25</date>
    <time>16:00</time>
  </event>
  <event>
    <date>2017-08-25</date>
    <time>20:00</time>
  </event>
  <event>
    <date>2017-08-26</date>
    <time>16:00</time>
  </event>
    <event>
    <date>2017-08-26</date>
    <time>20:00</time>
  </event>
    </event>
    <event>
    <date>2017-08-27</date>
    <time>20:00</time>
  </event>
</schedule>
```

To output the data I do using following loop:

```
<?php $xml = simplexml_load_file('events.xml'); ?>
<?php foreach ( $xml->event as $event ) { ?>
<dl>
    <dt>
        <?php echo $event->date; ?>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo $event->time; ?>
    </dd>
</dl>
<?php } ?>
```

The result is:

```
<dl>
    <dt>2017-08-25</dt>
    <dd>16:00</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>2017-08-25</dt>
    <dd>20:00</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>2017-08-26</dt>
    <dd>16:00</dd>
</dl>
```

etc.

But know I want to order the time by date, to get this output:

```
<dl>
    <dt>2017-08-25</dt>
    <dd>16:00</dd>
    <dd>20:00</dd>
</dl>

<dl>
    <dt>2017-08-26</dt>
    <dd>16:00</dd>
    <dd>20:00</dd>
</dl>
```

etc.

Is there a way to modify the loop, to get this result? I would be very thankfull for any help!

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204305/re-order-xml-results-based-on-xml-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files, because what you actually need is an XSLT 1.0 method called the [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) where you group by nodes using a document key and retrieve or manipulate all corresponding values.

PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts using its [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) extension (be sure to enable in .ini file). With this approach, no `foreach` loop or `if` logic needed.

**XSLT**  Script *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file that can be handled like any XML)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="eventid" match="event" use="date" />

  <xsl:template match="/schedule">
    <root>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="event"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="event">
    <dl>      
      <xsl:for-each select=".[generate-id() = generate-id(key('eventid', date)[1])]">
            <dt><xsl:value-of select="date"/></dt>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('eventid', date)">
                <dd><xsl:value-of select="time"/></dd>
            </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </dl>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** *(referencing above .xsl file)*

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('Input.xml');       // OR $xml->loadXML($xmlstring);

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');  // OR $xsl->loadXML($xslstring);

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// RUN TRANSFORMATION
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// ECHO STRING OUTPUT
echo $newXML;

// SAVE OUTPUT TO FILE
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXML);
```

Output *([online transform](http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrAo))*

```
<root>
   <dl>
      <dt>2017-08-25</dt>
      <dd>16:00</dd>
      <dd>20:00</dd>
   </dl>
   <dl/>
   <dl>
      <dt>2017-08-26</dt>
      <dd>16:00</dd>
      <dd>20:00</dd>
   </dl>
   <dl/>
   <dl>
      <dt>2017-08-27</dt>
      <dd>20:00</dd>
   </dl>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed steps to realize! I do like the way to use XSLT.  Sadly I forgot to mention, that I have no influence to modify the XML file. The file is based as API key on external servers.

Comment: You are not modifying the original XML but transforming original and saving to a new file. And if your output is just to screen, `echo $newXML;` should do.