# Sorting by x with simplexml and xpath

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting xml with simpleXML/xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293257/sorting-xml-with-simplexml-xpath)

I'm using SimpleXML and I'm trying to sort my list by the amount of views it has had. I have a generic foreach function that runs after the sorting as below:

```
    if($filter=="popular"){
        $sort=$x->xpath('//example[views]');
        function cmp($a, $b){
              if ( $a->id > $b->id) return -1;
              if ( $a->id < $b->id) return 1;
              return 0;
            }
        usort($sort, cmp); //this isn't working?
    } else {
        $sort = $x->example;
    }

    foreach($sort as $q){ ...
```

My XML looks something like:

```
    <list>
        <example>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>bob<name>
            <views>5</views>
        </example>
        <example>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>fred<name>
            <views>18</views>
    </example>
    <example>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>alfie<name>
        <views>0</views>
    </example>
</list>
```

So I just need a way to sort by the amount of views each example has had in DESC order - highest views to lowest views.

Any ideas?

Many thanks :)

Comment: I'm not using XSLT and they aren't using simpleXML in that question by the looks of it... unfortunately!

Comment: see Sjoerd's answer in the linked question.

Comment: That didn't answer my question either, it's still not in order.

Comment: because you are sorting by id and not by views

Answer (score 0):

That would be because you are using the function name as a constant and need to use it as a string like this: `usort($sort, 'cmp');` instead of `usort($sort, cmp);`

Comment: this is yet another error in the ops code but not the reason. php will use the cmp function to sort nonetheless.

Comment: @Gordon true, only issues a notice 10x for the heads up :)