# Sort by xpath using php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Below is my Xml, i need to sort by age using xpath in php

```
<Guest>
<Ages>
<Age>22</Age>
<Age>6</Age>
<Age>5</Age>
<Age>2</Age>
<Age>12</Age>
</Ages>
</Guest>
```

i try below code, but not working

```
foreach ($xd->xpath('Guest/Ages[descendant::Age]') as $xd_age)
        {
            echo $xd_age->Age.',';
        }
```

I need like below

```
Ages : 2,5,6,12,22
```

Comment: XPath by itself is designed for navigating XML documents, it doesn't really do manipulation or sorting. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17625078/628267) offers some options for sorting some values from XML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting XML with SimpleXML/XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293257/sorting-xml-with-simplexml-xpath)

Answer (score 1):

Consider an XSLT solution. As information, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) is a special purpose, declarative language designed specifically to manipulate XML files (not just a stylesheet for HTML). Practically all the general purpose languages, Java, C#, Perl, Python, VB, carry XSLT 1.0 processors including PHP -even command line programs like PowerShell and Bash. Various dedicated processors also exist such as open source [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) (which can run XSLT 2.0 scripts) and Apache's [Xalan](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/).

PHP can both embed or call an external XSLT script (.xsl or .xslt) which by the way is a well-formed XML file. Below is an embedded solution:

```
// Load the XML source
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('Input.xml');

$xslstr = '<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
            <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
            <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

              <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
              <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:template>  

              <!-- SORT AGE CHILDREN IN EACH AGES NODE -->
              <xsl:template match="Ages">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="Age">
                    <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:template>

            </xsl:transform>';

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->loadXML($xslstr);

// Configure the processor
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// Transform XML source
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc);    
echo $newXml;

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = 'Output.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXml);
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Guest>
  <Ages>
    <Age>2</Age>
    <Age>5</Age>
    <Age>6</Age>
    <Age>12</Age>
    <Age>22</Age>
  </Ages>
</Guest>
```