# Sorting Mulitdemensional Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array, it is currently created sorted by entity_count (outputted by a query done in cakephp - I only wanted the top few entities), I want to now sort the array for the Entity->title.

**I tried doing this with `array_multisort` but failed. Is this possible?**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Entity] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Orange
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [entitycount] => 76
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Entity] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Apple
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [entitycount] => 78
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Entity] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Lemon
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [entitycount] => 85
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a callback function like so:

```
function callback($value)
{
    return isset($value['entity']['title']) ? $value['entity']['title'] : null;
}
```

Then run it thew an array_map and multi sort

```
array_multisort(array_map($myArray,'callback'), $myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$keys = array_map($arr, function($val) { return $val['Entity']['title']; });
array_multisort($keys, $arr);
```

Here [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) and an [anonymous function](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) (available since PHP 5.3, you can use [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function) in prior versions) is used to get an array of the titles that is then used to sort the array according to their titles.

Comment: This is for PHP 5.3 only, and also Entity is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom compare function and then use [usort](http://php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php) .
Calll it using:

```
usort  ( $arrayy  , callback $cmp_function  );
```