# Sort php multidimensional array by sub-value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (

                [id] => 1293005125
                [viewed] => TRUE
                [active] => TRUE
                [time] => December 22, 2010 13:00 hours
                [timestamp] => 1293006034
                [initial_timestamp] => 1293005125
                [user] => administrator
            )

        [1] => Array
            (

                [mid] => 1293001908
                [viewed] => TRUE
                [active] => TRUE
                [time] => December 22, 2010 13:00 hours
                [timestamp] => 1293001908
                [initial_timestamp] => 1293001908
                [user] => administrator
            )

        [2] => Array
            (

                [mid] => 1293009999
                [viewed] => TRUE
                [active] => TRUE
                [time] => December 22, 2010 13:00 hours
                [timestamp] => 1293009999
                [initial_timestamp] => 1293009999
                [user] => administrator
            )

        [3] => Array
            (

                [mid] => 1293006666
                [viewed] => TRUE
                [active] => TRUE
                [time] => December 22, 2010 13:00 hours
                [timestamp] => 1293006666
                [initial_timestamp] => 1293006666
                [user] => administrator
            )

        [4] => Array
            (

                [mid] => 1293005125
                [viewed] => TRUE
                [active] => TRUE
                [time] => December 22, 2010 13:00 hours
                [timestamp] => 1293006125
                [initial_timestamp] => 1293005125
                [user] => administrator2
            )


    )
```

Now I would like to sort this array by `[mid]`
How do I do this?

Currently I sort this in a foreach loop
There has to be a better way

**EDIT**
I hoped to output something like

`[mid] key => array value`

Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a["mid"] - $b["mid"];
}
usort($arr, "cmp");
```

[**See it**](https://web.archive.org/web/20130429091044/http://ideone.com:80/cW5xZ)

Comment: Yes, but i found the examples a bit difficult to understand

Comment: @RisingSum: I've updated my answer with a working link.

Comment: As of 2013 (PHP 5+), we can nest the function inside the `usort` call as such: `usort($arr, function($a, $b) { return $a["mid"] - $b["mid"; });`

Comment: Here is the "See it" link from archive.org
https://web.archive.org/web/20130429091044/http://ideone.com:80/cW5xZ

Answer (score 35):

The other solution is using [**array_multisort**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
<?php
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $mid[$key]  = $row['mid'];
}

// Sort the data with mid descending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($mid, SORT_DESC, $data);
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Update

I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php/16788610#16788610) this question in a much more capable manner in the "definitive" topic on sorting multidimensional arrays. The answer below targets old versions of PHP (5.2 and earlier); while the concept is sound, nowadays there are much better ways of doing things. Read the answers on other question instead.

#### Original (very outdated) answer

[`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is there for exactly this situation. If you also need keys to be preserved, the appropriate function would be [`uasort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

For example:

```
usort($array, create_function('$a, $b',
   'if ($a["mid"] == $b["mid"]) return 0; return ($a["mid"] < $b["mid"]) ? -1 : 1;'));
```

Of course if you don't mind, you can declare the comparison function properly:

```
function compareMid($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['mid'] == $b['mid']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['mid'] < $b['mid']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
usort($array, 'compareMid');
```

All of this is in the documentation.