# multi dimensional array sorting from timestamp in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have this array i tried usort and array_multisort but both didn't worked. I want to sort each inner array with the release_date. Thats the latest release_date should come first in testing array and similarlly in second inner array 'test again'

```
$new_array = array(
    'testing' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 405275016,
            'release_date' => '2010-12-02 00:00:00'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 342809056,
            'release_date' => '2009-12-09 00:00:00'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 292430272,
            'release_date' => '2008-10-19 00:00:00'
        )
    )
    'test again' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 405275016,
            'release_date' => '2010-12-02 00:00:00'
        )
        array(
            'id' => 292430272,
            'release_date' => '2008-10-19 00:00:00'
        )
    )
);
```

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

***EDIT***

i did

```
foreach($new_array as $vsort) {
    uasort($vsort, function (array $a, array $b) { 
        return $a["release_date"] - $b["release_date"]; 
    });
}
```

but nothing happend to my `new_array`

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508145/sort-php-multidimensional-array-by-sub-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in `uasort()`.

If you want to sort *each* array then do a `foreach` loop and run `uasort()` on each one.

```
function mySort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['id'] < $b['id']) ? -1 : 1;
}

foreach ($array as $index => $arr) {
    uasort($array[$index], 'mySort');
}
```

http://codepad.org/TbNUiwBR

It appears you're using PHP 5.3. In that case, it can be rewritten like so:

```
foreach ($array as $index => $arr) {
    uasort($array[$index], function($a, $b) {
        if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['id'] < $b['id']) ? -1 : 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: this gave me a array as Array
(
    [testing] => 1
    [test again] => 1
) please see my edit

Comment: ya i tested. Its working perfectly. Thanks allot for the help. :)

Answer (score -1):

use foreach($new_array as $key => $val) and pass $new_array[$key] instead of $vsort, $vsort is the copy of array item and not the item itself