# Sort multidimensional array who has index

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array like that

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [UnitESN] => 14296
        [ScanNo] => 1
        [ScanDate] => Nov 21
        [ScanTime] => 10:15 AM
        [Qualifiers] => 
        [Notes] => 
        [BadgeData] => Array
            (
                [0] => HEATH---
                [1] => MCCU----
                [2] => HER---
                [3] => HCONNORS@------
                [4] => 
                [5] => 393
                [6] => 13350
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 111
            )

        [Signal] => +00/000
        [ConnectionDelay] => 0407
    )

     [1] => Array
```

And so on... I want to order ASC or DESC... let's say on Col 8 and Col 8 is entry number 7 (8-1 because it start at zero) in BadgeData, any ideas ? I've try array_multisort but without succes.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that you're looking for [`uasort`](http://ca2.php.net/uasort).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort php multidimensional array by sub-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508145/sort-php-multidimensional-array-by-sub-value)

Comment: If you want the credit Francois, post an answer. I found it! @Jon : Not the right answer in your "duplicate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you figured it out. Here's what I started writing before I got interrupted.

**Basic [`uasort`](https://www.php.net/uasort) Example:**

```
<?php

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['BadgeData'][7] == $b['BadgeData'][7]) {
        return 0;
    }
    // Ascending
    return ($a['BadgeData'][7] < $b['BadgeData'][7]) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Order the values of the array based on the value in BadgeData[7] in ascending order..
uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

It looks like I may have misunderstood your original question though as I thought you wanted to sort the array by the value in `BadgeData[7]` but it seems like you wanted to sort the BadgeData for each array value.

Comment: I have an array with [0] => [1] => etc... until like 1000 ... each array have a row named BadgeData. Inside that row, there's an array called [0], [1], [2], etc.. and it can be [2] and sometime it can be [50000] depend on what cie is it... so I need to sort by that. [1] can hold name or phone or even address that is why... but Thanks a lot, Ill mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Francois Deschenes to lead me on the right answer. Here's what I found :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php#104714

I edited to fit my need. Thanks !

```
function SortArrayByCol(array $Array, $Key, $ASC=true, $Col=0) {
    $Result = array();

    $Values = array();
    foreach($Array as $ID => $Value){
        $Values[$ID] = isset($Value[$Key][$Col]) ? $Value[$Key][$Col] : null;
    }

    if($ASC){
        asort($Values);
    } else {
        arsort($Values);
    }

    foreach($Values as $Key => $Value) {
        $Result[$Key] = $Array[$Key];
    }

    return $Result;
}
```