# Restructure array

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array with many values, this is minimized version of it:

```
$test = array(
    array(
       'name'   => 'test',
       'date'   => '2012-04-30 11:06:01'
    ),

    array(
       'name'   => 'test2',
       'date'   => '2012-04-30 11:07:00'
    )
);
```

And it just goes on...

Now dates are in random order, so i need to sort this array so it would be from smallest date to the biggest one, to be more clear i here is my full scale array dump: http://pastebin.com/EzTNJpUx and as you can see `sent` is the date and it goes in random order...

Comment: What have you tried? Also, there are *many* duplicates of this question on SO -- try searching some more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort php multidimensional array by sub-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508145/sort-php-multidimensional-array-by-sub-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use [usort](http://php.net/usort)**

From Manual:

> This function will sort an array by its values using a user-supplied comparison function. If the array you wish to sort needs to be sorted by some non-trivial criteria, you should use this function.

```
function cmp($a, $b){
     return strtotime($a['date'])-strtotime($b['date']);
}

usort($test, 'cmp');
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess you could use something like this,

usort() and DateTime class(if your using PHP5 or higher).

You you need to define a function to compare two elements(in this case, arrays also).

```
function cmp($array1, $array2)
{
  $date1 = new DateTime($array1['sent']);
  $date2 = new DateTime($array2['sent']);

  if($date1 == $date2)
    return 0;

  return ($date1 < $date2) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

then you call :

```
usort($test, 'cmp');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-multisort.php).