# Sort 2d array by column value

Tags: php, sorting

I'm breaking my head to sort array with key value. With this following array i need to sort this by **site_category** and i need to have output like

Example:

```
Shopping
   Amazon
Social
   Amoeblo
   American express
```

Array values are

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [site_id] => 1
            [site_name] => Amazon
            [site_img] => http://localhost/faves/resource/img/sites/icon/amazon.png
            [site_category] => Shopping
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [site_id] => 2
            [site_name] => Ameblo
            [site_img] => http://localhost/faves/resource/img/sites/icon/ameblow.png
            [site_category] => Social
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [site_id] => 3
            [site_name] => American Express
            [site_img] => http://localhost/faves/resource/img/sites/icon/americanexpress.png
            [site_category] => Social
        )


)
```

Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: So many answers to this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508145/sort-php-multidimensional-array-by-sub-value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: first problem: these aren't arrays, they're objects. They may usually behave like arrays, but not always. `site_category` isn't an array key it's an object property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a foreach and ksort

Let $your_array be the array you mentioned above

```
$res_array    = array();
foreach($your_array as $val){
   $res_array[$val->site_category][] = $val->site_name;
}
ksort($res_array);

print_r($res_array);
```

OR search for multisort in php which will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Virtually a duplicate of [Sort php multidimensional array by sub-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508145/sort-php-multidimensional-array-by-sub-value)

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $a->site_category - $b->site_category;
}
usort($arr, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp = array();
$i = 0;

for($i=0;$i<count($carriers);$i++){

    for($j=$i+1;$j<count($carriers);$j++){

        if($carriers[$i]['price']>$carriers[$j]['price']){

            $tmp = $carriers[$i];
            $carriers[$i] = $carriers[$j];
            $carriers[$j] = $tmp;
        }
    }
}       
return $carriers;
```

This sorts your `$carriers` array by it's price key.