# Sorting a Multidimensional Array by 1 of his value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

first of all, I did check and try thoses links:

> [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)
>
> [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)
>
> [Sort php multidimensional array by sub-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508145/sort-php-multidimensional-array-by-sub-value)
>
> http://www.paulund.co.uk/sort-multi-dimensional-array-value
>
> http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-multisort.php.

So there is my problem. I need to sort an array by value of a key into a multi-dimensional array.

This is the structure if I do : **print($myarray)**

```
Array ( 
    [afctname1] => Array ( 
    [active] => 1 
    [icons] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [permalink] => afctname1 
            [ordering] => 2 
        ) 
     ) 
 )
 Array ( 
    [afctname2] => Array ( 
    [active] => 1 
    [icons] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [permalink] => afctname2 
            [ordering] => 0 
        ) 
     ) 
 )
 Array ( 
    [afctname3] => Array ( 
    [active] => 1 
    [icons] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [permalink] => afctname3 
            [ordering] => 1 
        ) 
     ) 
 )
```

So all that I want is to sort the array by the value in the key "**ordering**".

Can some body give me a hint or help me with a demo or something?
Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you tried and what specifically went wrong.

Comment: did you search for `usort`?

Comment: So, is there always going to be exactly one `['icons'][0]['ordering']`? That seems weird. Also, what's going on with the opening array in `afctname*`? That invalidates the entire structure you're showing.

Comment: afctname is just a stringkey not really a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return $a['icons'][0]['ordering'] - $b['icons'][0]['ordering'];
}

usort($theArray, "cmp");
```

Comment: It work like a charm, thank you georg and Mex.