# PHP Sort array inside array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [2] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [3] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [4] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [5] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [6] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [7] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [8] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [9] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [10] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [11] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [12] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU100 [EmpName] => XXXXXX [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) )
            [1] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [2] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [3] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [4] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [5] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [6] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [7] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] =>90 [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [8] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [9] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [10] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [11] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [12] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU101 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => )
             [2] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [2] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [3] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [4] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [5] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [6] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [7] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] =>100 [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [8] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [9] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [10] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [11] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) 
                            [12] => Array ( [EmpId] => STU102 [EmpName] => YYYYY [percentage] => [max_point] => [opt_point] => ) ).....
```

I need the array sorted based on [percentage], ex: STU102 was 1st,STU101 was 2nd and STU100 was 3rd based on these manner i need to get the output, Can any one help me.
I tried,
When i use this means,

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  return $b[7]["percentage"] - $a[7]["percentage"];
}
usort($per_details1, "cmp");
```

it was sorted. But i give $b[7]["percentage"] - $a[7]["percentage"] 7 th index directly.

Comment: can you format your code?

Comment: can you correct your spelling, I don't understant ? is it "sort by Percentage" ?

Comment: @Babu to preserve spacing in your code, highlight the text and click the code button above the text editor. It looks like brackets: `{ }`

Comment: You can at least use an online tool to clean up the syntax : http://phpbeautifier.com/

Comment: But you have only one element with a percentage of 80... others have null (0%)..... your should have simulated an array with different percentages to make it easer for contributors to test their codes while helping you out.

Comment: @Poiz: This is my sample array poiz can you help me...

Comment: @BeetleJuice can you help my questions???

Comment: Barmar's code below is better than what I would have come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
in php along with [arraywalk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
function sort($a, $b) {
    if ($a['percentage'] == $b['percentage']) return 0;
    return ($a['percentage'] > $b['percentage']) ? 1 : -1;
}

function sort(&$value) {
    usort($value, 'sort');
}

array_walk($array, 'sort');
```

Comment: You may want to change the name of your function `sort` to something else like `mySort` because `sort` a built-in function and this code would raise an error..... ;-)

Comment: How does this sort by the `percentage` field in the array?

Comment: I use this code my dear friend, but not getting an exact result.

Comment: downvoted because it doesn't attempt to sort by `percentage` as the OP requested.

Comment: @BeetleJuice 
 
changed the code to sort by percentage, missed that part before

Comment: removed the downvote

Comment: @Poiz Valid concern, But I was just trying to point in the right direction not providing the exact code :P

Comment: @SatyapalSharma    Perfect!!! It was also imagined that, "that was your intention"... however the concern was only because the OP might not see it that way since he's probably a beginner judging from his question & SO Reputation and anyways +10 for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Loop over your array and use `usort()` to sort them by the `percentage` field in the sub-arrays. Use a reference variable in the `foreach` loop so it operates on the arrays in place.

```
foreach ($array as &$subarray) {
    usort ($subarray, function ($a, $b) {
        return $a['percentage'] - $b['percentage'];
    }
}
```

Comment: would you have any kind of relationship with oBArMAr?.....Seriously, it's an honest Curiosity..... It's just that you look like an Authority Figure ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With a blend of  `array_walk` and `usort`; you can get the job done. The Code below illustrates how.

**In Brief: to get the job done**

```
    <?php

        // FIRST; SORT THE MAIN ARRAY IN REVERSE ORDER...
        rsort($mdArray);

        // IF YOU WANT TO SORT BY ANY OTHER FIELD, SAY "EmpId"
        // YOU CAN SIMPLY CHANGE THE DEFAULT VALUE OF $field to "EmpId"
        function sortByField($prev, $next, $field="percentage") {
            return $next[$field] - $prev[$field];
        }

        array_walk($mdArray, function(&$data){
            usort($data, "sortByField");
        });
```

**In details: with a sample Array:**

```
    <?php
        $mdArray    = array(
            array (
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 15, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 78, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 20 ,"max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 10, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 77, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 34, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 22, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 78, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 49, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 55, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 36, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU100", "EmpName" => "XXXXXX", "percentage" => 18, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" =>  null,)
            ),
            array (
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 70, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 54, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 23, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 46, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 10, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 21, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 80, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 34, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 50, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 27, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 39, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
                array( "EmpId" => "STU101", "EmpName" => "YYYYY", "percentage" => 12, "max_point" => null, "opt_point" => null, ),
            ),
        );


        // FIRST; SORT THE MAIN ARRAY IN REVERSE ORDER...
        rsort($mdArray);

        // IF YOU WANT TO SORT BY ANY OTHER FIELD, SAY "EmpId"
        // YOU CAN SIMPLY CHANGE THE DEFAULT VALUE OF $field to "EmpId"
        function sortByField($prev, $next, $field="percentage") {
            return $next[$field] - $prev[$field];
        }

        array_walk($mdArray, function(&$data){
            usort($data, "sortByField");
        });

        var_dump($mdArray);
```

The `var_dump` above produces something like the result below. Notice, now, that the array is sorted by percentages in Descending Order. If you want to reverse the process (ie. sort in Ascending Order), simply swap `$next` and `$prev` within (inside) the function: `sortByField`.

```
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=12)
              0 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 78
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              1 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 78
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              2 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 77
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              3 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 55
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              4 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 49
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              5 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 36
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              6 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 34
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              7 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 22
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              8 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 20
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              9 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 18
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              10 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 15
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              11 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU100' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=6)
                  'percentage' => int 10
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
          1 => 
            array (size=12)
              0 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 80
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              1 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 70
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              2 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 54
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              3 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 50
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              4 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 46
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              5 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 39
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              6 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 34
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              7 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 27
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              8 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 23
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              9 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 21
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              10 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 12
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
              11 => 
                array (size=5)
                  'EmpId' => string 'STU101' (length=6)
                  'EmpName' => string 'YYYYY' (length=5)
                  'percentage' => int 10
                  'max_point' => null
                  'opt_point' => null
```

Test it out [here](https://eval.in/607659).

Comment: Thank You Friend, I need the 2 nd array to 1st first to second like that ex: STU101 should came first,STU100 came 2nd like that i need the array... Can you please help me...

Comment: @Babu   You may try out the updated code again... (if you wish)

Comment: @Babu   That's why SO exists.... ;-) You may want to check/mark the answer  as the right one , though (if you wish)

Comment: Still i am not get the result...

Answer (score 0):

**You really should format your code when you post it.**

You can use PHP's usort to accomplish what you're after. See the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508145/sort-php-multidimensional-array-by-sub-value).

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a["mid"] - $b["mid"];
}
usort($arr, "cmp");
```

Also, while we are happy to help here on SO, you should do some of your own research into your problem as well.

Comment: function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a["mid"] - $b["mid"];
}
usort($arr, "cmp"); I already used this but not get the result, my array i like array inside array...

Comment: Can you answer my Question.