# Sort multidimensional array by date column, then use other column values if dates are the same

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

I have a multidimensional array that stores people.

```
Array (
   id93294 => array (
       Name => "Tom Anderson",
       Birthday => "03/17/1975",
       Hometown => 'St. Louis',
       CurrentLocation => 'Mars'
   ),
   id29349 => (array (
       Name => "Tom Anderson",
       Birthday => "03/17/1975",
       Hometown => 'New York',
       CurrentLocation => 'New York'
   )
)
```

Kind of like that except with more info for the people, so I want to first sort by birthdays THEN sort by another attribute (if their hometown matches their current location) but once I do the second sort on the array it loses the first sort I did using the birthdays...

How do I sort multiple times without it messing up my previous sorts.

P.S. I am using uasort.

Comment: Don't do consecutive sorts; define your sort functor properly to take account of all the layers of the tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update

I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php/16788610#16788610) this question in a much more capable manner in the "definitive" topic on sorting multidimensional arrays. You can safely skip reading the rest of this answer and directly follow the link for a much more capable solution.

#### Original answer

The function `uasort` lets you define your own comparison function. Simply put all the criteria you want inside that.

For example, to sort by birthday and then by name:

```
function comparer($first, $second) {
    // First see if birthdays differ
    if ($first['birthday'] < $second['birthday']) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ($first['birthday'] > $second['birthday']) {
        return 1;
    }

    // OK, birthdays are equal. What else?
    if ($first['name'] < $second['name']) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ($first['name'] > $second['name']) {
        return 1;
    }

    // No more sort criteria. The two elements are equal.
    return 0;
}
```

I am ignoring the fact that in your example, the birthdays are not in a format that can be ordered by a simple comparison using the operator `<`. In practice you would convert them to a trivially-comparable format first.

**Update:** if you think that maintaining a bunch of these multiple-criteria comparers could get ugly real fast, you find me in agreement. But this problem can be solved as any other in computer science: just add another level of abstraction.

I 'll be assuming PHP 5.3 for the next example, in order to use the convenient anon function syntax. But in principle, you could do the same with `create_function`.

```
function make_comparer() {
    $criteriaNames = func_get_args();
    $comparer = function($first, $second) use ($criteriaNames) {
        // Do we have anything to compare?
        while(!empty($criteriaNames)) {
            // What will we compare now?
            $criterion = array_shift($criteriaNames);

            // Do the actual comparison
            if ($first[$criterion] < $second[$criterion]) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if ($first[$criterion] > $second[$criterion]) {
                return 1;
            }

        }

        // Nothing more to compare with, so $first == $second
        return 0;
    };

    return $comparer;
}
```

You could then do:

```
uasort($myArray, make_comparer('birthday', 'name'));
```

This example possibly tries to be too clever; in general I don't like to use functions that do not accept their arguments by name. But in this case, the usage scenario is a very strong argument for being too clever.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question.

This pseudo-code comes from the definition of the problem you gave and is intended to be the callback function given to `uasort`. I cannot fill in the details because you've omitted the code you're using; hopefully this leads you on the right track.

```
function compare(p1, p2):
    if birthdays of p1 and p2 are not the same
        compare by birthday
    else
        compare by hometown
```

If someone could verify that this is a valid comparison function for a sort algorithm in the comments, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Many years later, there is a cleaner, more succinct technique provided from PHP7+ ...the spaceship operator and balanced arrays of "criteria".

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Gi9kkj))

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return [strtotime($a['Birthday']), $a['Hometown'] !== $a['CurrentLocation'], $a['Name']]
           <=>
           [strtotime($b['Birthday']), $b['Hometown'] !== $b['CurrentLocation'], $b['Name']];
});
var_export($array);
```

See the demo link for sample input and the output.

This snippet will sort by:

1. Birthday ASC then
2. Hometown === CurrentLocation before not === then
3. Name ASC

Note: #2 has `!==` syntax only because `false` evaluation are treated as 0 and `true` evaluations are treated as 1.

If you need to change any of the sorting orders for any of the criteria, just swap the `$a` and `$b` at the corresponding elements.