# How can I sort an array after a member of its items in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting

I have problem sorting dates in an array.

```
$data[0]["Venue"];
$data[0]["VenueConfigurationID"];
$data[0]["VenueID"];
$data[0]["TimeStamp"];

$data[2]["Venue"];
$data[2]["VenueConfigurationID"];
$data[2]["VenueID"];
$data[2]["TimeStamp"];

$data[3]["Venue"];
$data[3]["VenueConfigurationID"];
$data[3]["VenueID"];
$data[3]["TimeStamp"];
```

I want to sort these arrays based on the TimeStamp value.

Comment: TimeStamp is in integer form.

Comment: All-caps is the internet equivalent of shouting. Please refrain from doing that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the solution I presented for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198276/php-multiple-uasort-functions-breaks-sorting/5198370#5198370) (see the code for the `make_comparer` function):

```
usort($data, make_comparer('TimeStamp'));
```

This will let you sort the data by any number of criteria, and you can easily change the criteria by simply changing the order or the value of the array items.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). Using this function, you can specify a comparison function that shall be used to compare two elements. Thus, you could write

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['timestamp'] == $b['timestamp']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['timestamp'] < $b['timestamp']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

and afterwards:

```
usort($data, "cmp");
```

Comment: I have tried it.<br> '' function cmp($a, $b) {
    global $array;
    if($array[$a]['TimeStamp'] < $array[$b]['TimeStamp']){
  return false;
 }else{
  return true;
 }
}''

Comment: @Charlie: Why the `global $array`? `$a` and `$b` are elements directly from your array. Moreover: Why returning `true` or `false`?

Comment: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/fani/Desktop/C2%20Help/Sample.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
$a_t = strtotime( $a['TimeStamp'] ) ; 
$b_t = strtotime( $b['TimeStamp'] ) ; 

if ($a_t == $b_t) {
    return 0;
}
return ($a_t < $b_t) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($data,'cmp');
```

hope it works

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of correct answers here, but I usually prefer to use `usort` with anonymous functions:

### PHP ≥ 5.3

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['timestamp'] - $b['timestamp'];
});
```

### PHP ≥ 4.0.1

```
usort($data, create_function('$a, $b',
    'return $a["timestamp"] - $b["timestamp"];'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**array_multisort**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) function:-

```
<?php
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $timestamp[$key]  = $row['TimeStamp'];        
}

// Sort the data with timestamp descending    
array_multisort($timestamp, SORT_DESC, $data);
?>
```

Hope this helps.