# How to add additional parameters to usort/uasort cmp function?

Tags: php

I would like to have this $sort_flags array available within the compare_by_flags function, but I didn't find a way to this, is it possible?

```
public function sort_by_rank(array $sort_flags = array()) {
    uasort($this->search_result_array, array($this, 'compare_by_flags'));
}

private static function compare_by_flags($a, $b) {
    // I want to have this $sort_flags array here to compare according to those flags      
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use php < 5.3 then you can just use instance variables:

```
public function sort_by_rank(array $sort_flags = array()) {
    $this->sort_flags = $sort_flags;
    uasort($this->search_result_array, array($this, 'compare_by_flags'));
}

private static function compare_by_flags($a, $b) {
    // I want to have this $sort_flags array here to compare according to those flags      
}
```

otherwise - use closures:

```
public function sort_by_rank(array $sort_flags = array()) {
    uasort($this->search_result_array, function($a, $b) use ($sort_flags) {
        // your comparison
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, using the first approach and will switch as soon we upgrade php

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention what you want to achieve by passing the `$sort_flags` variable, but you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198276/php-multiple-uasort-functions-breaks-sorting/5198370#5198370) of mine useful (either as it stands, or as an example if you want to achieve something different).

Answer (score -1):

You could set it as class static property, like this:

```
public function sort_by_rank(array $sort_flags = array()) {
    self::$_sort_flags = $sort_flags;
    uasort($this->search_result_array, array($this, 'compare_by_flags'));
}

private static function compare_by_flags($a, $b) {
    // Read self::$_sort_flags
    // I want to have this $sort_flags array here to compare according to those flags      
}
```

Also you could try this, as of PHP 5.3

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
  self::compare_by_flags($a, $b, $sort_flags);
});
```

Comment: This exact code will not work, as long as anonymous function variable scope has no idea what `$sort_flags` is.